# What is the easiest way to reset ERRORLEVEL to zero?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I have a post-build event that runs some commands for a c# project. The last command would sometimes cause the ERRORLEVEL value not equals to zero and then the build fails.

I want to append an extra line of command to always set the ERRORLEVEL value to zero. What is the most convenient way to do that?

Comment: The build doesn't really fail, only the IDE does look like it.

Comment: I realize this is a pretty old post... I had success in resetting the errorlevel to 0 by issuing the command "type nul" after the last command. Just felt it might be of use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found that "exit 0" looks like a good way to deal with this problem.

Usage Example:

> NET STOP UnderDevService /Y
>
> exit 0

if the UnderDevService service is not started.

Comment: not if you also want to run that batch file from the command line, as exit 0 will close the window. cmd /c "exit /b 0" as suggested below is much more bening

Answer (score 77):

if you use `exit /b 0` you can return an `errorlevel 0` from within a child batch script  without also exiting the parent.

Comment: Out of all the proposed solutions, this is probably be the best one. I'm going to toss this line into a *resetErrorlevel.bat* script.

All in all, the fact that one has to go to such lengths to do something as trivial as clearing a script's error level is yet more proof that the inventor of Windows batch programming should be hunted down and punished harshly. ;)

Answer (score 59):

Seems to do the trick:

```
ver > nul
```

Not everything works, and it is not clear why. For example, the following do not:

```
echo. > nul
cls > nul
```

Comment: I think the reason of why "echo" and "cls" don't work is because they are the shell built-in commands, not real programs.

Comment: I'll give you that, but where is ver.exe?

Comment: I can't find "ver.exe" or "ver.com" either. I don't know how to explain that.

Comment: At batch command line, "ver" returns the MS windows version, eg "Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]".

Comment: if you run help in command shell, you will see ver is also a built in command

Comment: @BaiyanHuang - I'm nearly positive `"ver"` is an internal command, but how can you tell from `"help"` ?  Many of the commands listed in `"help"` are "external" commands like: `Find.exe`, `Findstr.exe`, `Help.exe`, `Subst.exe`, `Wmic.exe`, `Xcopy.exe`, ...

Answer (score 36):

In a pre- or post-build event, if the return code of an executable is greater than zero, and the call to the executable is not the last line of the pre- or post-build event, a quick way to mute it and avoid triggering a check for a non-zero `errorlevel` is to follow the failing line with a line that explicitly returns zero:

```
cmd /c "exit /b 0"
```

This is essentially a generic combination of the previously-mentioned solutions that will work with more than *just* the last line of a pre- or post-build event.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. the easier sounding suggestion of 'exit 0' above doesn't cut it as I wish to continue doing stuff after resetting the errorlevel, not exit

Comment: even more fancy: you can use `<some failing command> || cmd /c "exit /b 0"` as a one liner.

Comment: I like this method for ***setting*** an arbitrary errorlevel like: `cmd /c "exit /b 9009"`, but it seems a bit overkill for setting it to 0. Wouldn't `ver > nul` (an internal command), work just as well with less overhead than loading another copy of the command shell with `cmd /c "exit /b 0"` ?

Comment: The `/b` is not needed so `cmd /c “exit 0”` works fine too.

Comment: I like this one does the job. Thanks. One funny thing im tracing some file and my error level kept changing to 1, finally i found that prompting the user like (set /p id="enter id") changes the errorlevel to 1! ... I had filled the b

Comment: I like this since it does what it says

Answer (score 23):

I personally use this:

`cd .`

Works even in unix shell.

But, this one might be a bit faster:

`type nul>nul`

Because `Process Monitor` shows `QueryDirectory` calls on `cd .`

**PS:**
`cd .` has another nice side effect in the unix shell. It does restore recreated working directory in the terminal if it has been opened before the erase.

**Update**:

And that is a bit more faster:

```
call;
```

`Any windows command to find if a file is in use or not ?` :
https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5542

Answer (score 9):

I use `VERIFY` or `VERIFY > nul`

Answer (score 6):

If this is a snippet like "Post-build Event" etc., then you'll be fine appending:

```
(...) || ver > nul
```

at the end of the last command.

Alternatively

```
cmd /c "exit /b 0"
```

is very clean and non-idiomatic -- a reader who knows Windows shell will know what's going on, and what was your intent.

However, if you're in a batch script, you may want to use subrotines, which are a lightweight equivalent of the "child batch script" from akf's answer.

Have a subroutine:

```
:reset_error
exit /b 0
```

and then just

```
call :reset_error
```

wherever you need it.

Here's a complete example:

```
@echo off
rem *** main ***

call :raise_error
echo After :raise_error ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%

call :empty
echo After :empty ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%

call :reset_error
echo After :reset_error ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%

:: this is needed at the end of the main body of the script
goto:eof

rem *** subroutines ***

:empty
goto:eof

:raise_error
exit /b 1

:reset_error
exit /b 0
```

Which outputs:

```
After :raise_error ERRORLEVEL = 1
After :empty ERRORLEVEL = 1
After :reset_error ERRORLEVEL = 0
```

As you see - just calling and returning via goto:eof is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

The following works in modern Windows (NT-based) systems that feature `cmd.exe`:

```cmd
rem /* This clears `ErrorLevel`; the SPACE can actually be replaced by an
rem    arbitrary sequence of SPACE, TAB, `,`, `;`, `=`, NBSP, VTAB, FF: */
(call )
```

The <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (or more precisely, an arbitrary sequence of one or more standard token separators, which are <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (code `0x20`), <kbd>TAB</kbd> (code `0x09`), `,`, `;`, `=`, <kbd>NBSP</kbd> (code `0xFF`), <kbd>VTAB</kbd> (code `0x0B`) and <kbd>FF</kbd> (code `0x0C`)) is mandatory; if you omit it the `ErrorLevel` becomes set instead:

```cmd
rem // This sets `ErrorLevel` to `1`:
(call)
```

There is a nice thread on [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4308&p=24176#p24187) where this technique came up.

---

Here is an alternative method, but which accesses the file system and might therefore be a bit slower:

```cmd
dir > nul

rem /* Perhaps this is a little faster as a specific file is given rather 
rem    than just the current directory (`.` implicitly) like above: */
dir /B "%ComSpec%" > nul
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other ways to reset the `ErrorLevel` state, which even work in MS-DOS (at least for version 6.22):

```cmd
more < nul > nul

rem // The `> nul` part can be omitted in Windows but is needed in MS-DOS to avoid a line-break to be returned:
sort < nul > nul
```

---

The following methods work in MS-DOS only:

```cmd
command /? > nul

fc nul nul > nul

keyb > nul
```

---

For the sake of completeness, this sets the `ErrorLevel` state to `1`, valid for both Windows and MS-DOS:

```cmd
< nul find ""
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing all of the other answers, I decided to find which way was the most efficient for resetting the ERRORLEVEL. I made a quick script that recorded the time to execute each of these:

```
"cmd /c "exit /b 0"", "cd .", "ver", "type nul", and "VERIFY"
```

here is the output:

> cmd /v:on /c set ^"q=^"^" & timeit.cmd "cmd /c ^!q^!exit /b 0^!q^!" "cd ." "ver" "type nul" "VERIFY"
>
> cmd /c "exit /b 0" took 0:0:0.02 (0.02s total)
>
> cd . took 0:0:0.00 (0.00s total)
>
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]
>
> ver took 0:0:0.00 (0.00s total)
>
> type nul took 0:0:0.00 (0.00s total)
>
> VERIFY is off.
>   VERIFY took 0:0:0.00 (0.00s total)
>
> ---
>
> This took 0:0:0.06 (0.06s total)

after reviewing with `Measure-Command {command}` in Powershell, I found that it only really accepted `cd .` and `cmd /c "exit /b 0"` --am I doing something wrong?

I'd recommend either `cd .` or `type nul` since neither have a footprint on the output of the console, nor are they slow in any measure.

yeah I'm pretty bored

Comment: Yes, `cmd /C exit [/B] 0` should be the slowest since a new `cmd.exe` instance is opened and closed; the others are all internal commands, so there is no file system access to find executable files…

Answer (score 0):

Add `>nul` after each command that's likely to fail - this seems to prevent the build from failing.

You can still check the result of the command by examining `%errorlevel%`.

For example:

```
findstr "foo" c:\temp.txt>nul & if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (echo found it) else (echo didn't find it)
```

Comment: This won't work -- the shell evaluates the entire command line at once, so %errorlevel% will be substituted before the "findstr" command is executed.  Use "if errorlevel 1" instead to test for a non-zero errorlevel.

Comment: Probably your CI server fails builds if it for example finds the string "error" in the standard output / standard error. You're not resetting the status. You're just silencing the command. For a deeper silence use  >nul 2>nul

Answer (score 0):

User aschipfl gave best answer, to complete it, using smallest function FIND:

This line will set ERRORLEVEL to 1, in DOS or later:

```
<nul find ""
if errorlevel 1 echo ERRORLEVEL is 1 or more
```

This line will set ERRORLEVEL to 0, in DOS or later:

```
echo a |find "a" >nul
if errorlevel==0 echo No Error
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried all solutions above - nothing worked. But found this solution that works for me inside the batch file:

```
set /A errorlevel=0
```

(the /A switch defines the supplied value as a numerical expression)

Comment: DO NOT do this! It overrides the "magic" system variable, which then doesn't work correctly anymore until you "unset" this variable.

Answer (score -3):

I'm using this:

ping localhost -n 1 >null

Answer (score -7):

I always just used;

```
set ERRORLEVEL=0
```

I've been using it for donkey's years.

Comment: It's easy but it´s a really bad idea, as this creates a variable named `errorlevel` which overlays the internal pseudo variable `errorlevel`

Comment: Crikey, you're right! Wow, looks like I've been dodging bullets for years :)