# How to echo "2" (no quotes) to a file, from a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo, io-redirection

How do I echo the number *2* into a file, from a batch script?

This doesn't work:

```
Echo 2>> file.txt
```

because `2>>` is a special command. :(

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use `(ECHO 2)>>file.txt`. This will output `2` without any spaces.

Comment: +1 OH MY GOSH that's brilliant! I totally didn't think of that. :)

Comment: Except when it has parentheses (right?). :P Now (this is a separate question, obviously) how do I echo an *arbitrary file name* to another file? It could have parentheses, quotes, numbers, etc...

Comment: You know, I think I'll ask that as a separate question. :)

Comment: Awesome solution, but looks like there *still* might be a CRLF behind. How do we handle this unstoppable threat?

Comment: The answer  at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589300/3923957) shows how to echo the number 2 to a file without the CRLF behind.

Answer (score 340):

Little-known feature: The redirection operator can go anywhere on the line.

```
>>file.txt echo 2
```

Answer (score 36):

`echo ^2>>file.txt` appears to work for me.

Comment: But there is **still** a CRLF behind (giving us 3 bytes). How can that be stopped?

Comment: @Pacerier -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589300/3923957) for how to echo the number 2 to a file without the CRLF behind.

Comment: @Pacerier Are you sure that it is a requirement of the OP?

Answer (score 31):

Use the `^` escape :

```
Echo ^2>> file.txt
```

Comment: Btw what's the logic behind this?

Comment: @Pacerier - the "2" in this context would have a special meaning. So the ^ escape character is used to treat the "2" like a normal character.

Answer (score 11):

```
echo.2>>text.txt
```

Yes, it's weird.

Comment: It's weird, and it works only if there is no space/tab nor any of `,;=(`. This one `echo.hello(you2>>text.txt` fails

Comment: @Kornel, But there is **still** a CRLF behind (giving us 3 bytes). How can that be stopped?

Comment: The answer at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589300/3923957) shows how to echo the number 2 to a file without the CRLF behind.

Comment: `echo.` could fail if there is a file named `echo.` (no extension) in the current directory, so better use `echo/`...

Answer (score 10):

another method

```
echo>>file.txt 2
```

Comment: But there is **still** a CRLF behind (giving us 3 bytes). How can that be stopped?

Comment: The answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589300/3923957) shows how to echo the number 2 to a file without the CRLF behind.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use the delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=2"
echo(!var!>> file.txt
```

Comment: But there is **still** a CRLF behind (giving us 3 bytes). How can that be stopped?

Comment: The answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589300/3923957) shows how to echo the number 2 to a file without the CRLF behind.

Answer (score 3):

If you need an accurate write, use this command

```
(ECHO |set /p=2)>>file.txt
```

the command by DMan will produce a 0x0D0A line break behind the "2"

Comment: This will set ERRORLEVEL to 1. If it is preferred to set ERRORLEVEL to 0, you could use something like `(echo | set /p dummyName="2") > file.txt` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336754/3923957)).

Comment: You could avoid the pipe and use this: `< nul set /P ="2" > file.txt`, but then `ErrorLevel` becomes `1`, even with a dummy variable...

Comment: @headinabook not only is it not cleaner, it will set errorlevel to 0. (if you want 0 just `(call )`!

Answer (score 2):

To write a number to a file without a trailing line-break you could use the following:

```cmd
cmd /C set /A "2">file.txt
```

This works, because `set /A` returns the (last) result (without line-break) when executed in command prompt context (hence when directly run in `cmd.exe`).

If you are working in command prompt anyway, you could simply use this:

```cmd
set /A "2">file.txt
```

Though you cannot use that in a batch file, you need the extra `cmd /C` to force the right execution context.

Needless to say, this can of course only output numbers, or precisely said, signed 32-bit integers.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225667/1637178) answer, if anyone is wondering how to do this:

```
echo "command1 && command2" > file.txt
```

with no qoutes in `file.txt` then you do it like this:

```
echo command1 ^&^& command2 > file.txt
```

Tested on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Well, how does this answer the question?

Comment: I should probably rephrase my post. It is a supplement to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225667/1637178.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it; this is not echoing a number to a file...

Answer (score -1):

escape the haracter '2'

in linux:
`echo \2>file.txt`

in windows:
`echo ^2>file.txt`

in windows this also will work

`echo.2>file.txt` no space between echo and the dot