# echo / batch redirect to file automatically appends space?

Tags: windows, cmd, echo

When executing

```
echo 0 > test.txt
```

in cmd.exe, the output in test.txt is

> 0_

where _ means space. Why is there a space appended? Any way to prevent the appending of the space? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to echo "2" (no quotes) to a file, from a batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225630/how-to-echo-2-no-quotes-to-a-file-from-a-batch-script)

Comment: Yes, however from the title one wouldn't expect it's the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space that gets appended is the space between the "0" and the ">" in your command line. There is a non-obvious way to get rid of it: *prepend* the redirection to the command instead:

```
>test.txt echo 0
```

Comment: You can also just leave the space out (echo 0>test.txt) but your way is cuter.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, you can, but did you try that command? Did you see the output? Single-digit numbers are special case when they are immediately followed by redirection. (They are treated as file handles.)

Comment: @AndriyM: Very true.  Good catch.

Comment: @Jon: Works great thank you! Harry: I also tried that once, but like Andriy said - not working ;-)

Comment: Hmm while this appends no space it appends a new line - any way to get rid of that?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/hidden-features-of-windows-batch-files/374361#374361.