# Is it possible to echo some non-printable characters in batch/cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, carriage-return, non-printing-characters

**motivation**

I have a 3rd party, somehow long .bat file written for some specific function and would take considerable effort to re-write (which effort is also hindered by my problem). In for loops the most basic way to debug it would seem echoing some information to the screen. I used to do this with `\r` (0x0D) character in other languages that on some terminals/console re-writes the same line (to avoid overflooding, since in my case the last line would contain the error). I already save the value to a variable. However, since iteration might take quite long, I'd still be happy to write some output to the screen that won't overflood.

**what I've tried**

- I know I can echo a single newline in `cmd` with `echo.` - however I need only the carriage return
- I've tried these but they did't work: `echo \r`, `echo ^r`, `echo \x0d`, `echo ^x0d`, `echo #0d`, `echo ^#0d`, `echo #x0d`, `echo ^x0d`
- I've tried to [duck the net](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22batch%22+%22echo%22+%22carriage%22+retirn+%220D%22) for similar stuff without much help

**question**

Is it possible to somehow echo a carriage-return (or other non-printable) character in a windows/dos/nt/cmd batch file?

ps. I use the XP or the 7 cmd processor

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line

Comment: @Stephan thanks, using http://stackoverflow.com/a/13941131/611007 it seems possible albeit with the [gnuwin32's coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) package: `echo blah | tr -d "\n"` :) not too optimal but at least it works!

Comment: [How to overwrite the same line in command output from batch file](https://superuser.com/q/82929/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clear ONLY ONE LINE of cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450295/how-do-i-clear-only-one-line-of-cmd)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need two hacks - one to define a carriage return character, and another to echo a line of text without issuing the newline character.

**1) Define carriage return.**

```
:: Define CR to contain a carriage return (0x0D)
for /f %%A in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%A"
```

Once defined, the value can only be accessed via delayed expansion - as in `!CR!`, not `%CR%`.

**2) Print text to the screen without issuing a newline**

```
<nul set /p "=Your message here"
```

This will fail if the string starts with a `=`.

Also, leading quotes and/or white space may be stripped, depending on the Windows version

**Putting it all together**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define CR to contain a carriage return (0x0D)
for /f %%A in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%A"

<nul set/p"=Part 1 - press a key!CR!"
pause >nul
<nul set/p"=Part 2 - press a key!CR!"
pause >nul
<nul set/p"=Part 3 - Finished   !CR!"
```

Note that I put the `!CR!` at the end of each message in preparation for the next. You cannot put the `!CR!` at the beginning because leading white space will be stripped.

Comment: ahhh - I was so close. My solution did not work, because I had the !cr! at the beginning of the string. Thank you for the explanation. +1

Comment: docs for the CR hack: it relies on a specific behaviour of the `/Z` [switch of copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx). about `%~dfp0", see [Using batch file parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx)

Comment: What if at the time I print message I don't know if I will need to continue in print without CR or not? Any chance to do some workaround about printing `!CR!` separately, or with some non-standard white space, such as `chr(160) + CR` to allowed to use CR only when really needed?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the line,   "echo\"  works to print a [cr] line.  Great for ending an output from some other command that doesn't put [cr] at the end. 
I've used this for sending CR to files  as in   IPconfig | find "Reply" >>myip.txt    and then  echo\ >>myip.txt

Comment: No, that outputs `<CR><LF>` (carriageReturn and LineFeed), but the OP is looking for only `<CR>`.

Comment: Upvoted: not OP's question but very useful (I was looking for this).

Comment: OP question is to "echo a carriage-return (or other non-printable) character "

Answer (score 1):

Building on dbenham's post, I have the following routines that work in Win7 and mostly editable in Notepad; however, I used Scite to generate the <kbd>backspace</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>, character. It differs slightly by first clearing the row, and placing the cursor at the end of the text. Here are the routines:

```
:RECHO
<nul set/p"=backspace!CR!tabtabtabtabtabtabtabtabtabtab"
<nul set/p"=backspace!CR!%*"
GOTO :EOF
```

```
:NECHO
<nul set/p"=backspace!CR!tabtabtabtabtabtabtabtabtabtab"
ECHO backspace!CR!%*
GOTO :EOF
```

dbenham's example modified:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F %%a IN ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') DO SET "CR=%%a"
SET "BS="

ECHO Testing CR. This line a regular echo ...
CALL :RECHO Part 1 - press a key
pause >nul
CALL :RECHO Part 2 - press a key
pause >nul
CALL :NECHO Part 3 - Finished
ECHO Testing CR. This line a regular echo ...
GOTO END

:RECHO
<nul set/p"=!BS!!CR!                                                "
<nul set/p"=!BS!!CR!%*"
GOTO :EOF

:NECHO
<nul set/p"=!BS!!CR!                                                "
ECHO !BS!!CR!%*
GOTO :EOF

:END
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B
```

When copying the above script, make sure the <kbd>backspace</kbd> character is preserved.

```
    SET "BS=backspace"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I catch & `echo` 0x0A in cmd:

```
(
set n=^

)
```

Then to test:

```
echo Ila!n!you
echo Ila!n!!n!you
set /p="la!n!"<nul > newline
```

You may see the written file via hex viewer eg `fc` or `comp`

```
00000000: 00 6C
00000001: 00 61
00000002: 00 0A
```

Tested in Win 10 CMD

Comment: to overwrite the last line, `LF` isn't helpful at all. You'd need `CR`. The question wasn't about echoing a linefeed, but (over)writing to the same line again and again.

Comment: @Stephan: The question in the section "question" is "to somehow echo a carriage-return (or other non-printable) character". Read the question before you start voting on other's answers, esp. if you can't come up with an answer yourself!

Comment: A carriage-return (`CR`) sets the cursor at the start of the current line. A Linefeed (`LF`) sets the cursor to the next line. Different things (yes, I read the question...). And there are several good answers, so why should I clutter this page with a similar answer? Btw you shouldn't assume by default that a downvote is necessarily from a commenter (it is in this case, but it's mostly not).

Comment: @Stephan: `CR` is different from `LF`. Do you know any other way to `echo` "non-printable"s from CMD? Feel free to share. (without any externals, of course ideally without JS, HTA, VBS, or downloads)

Comment: [Dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) has listed a great collection of methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826309/2152082).