# How do I clear ONLY ONE LINE of cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, I have added some stuff in cmd. I want there to be a progress bar using text, so that it is like [.........   ], but when I type in CLS to clear the line and ECHO to remake with an extra one, CLS clears the entire screen. I want it to clear ONLY ONE LINE! How do I do it?

I know there is NOT a command that does that, but using the FOR command, is it possible to do it with FOR and some other stuff (BUT NOT ANY THIRD PARTIES)?

I hope the answer is yes.

Here's an example of what I want and don't want:

https://ou.wistia.com/medias/xkxld1i3vy

This doesn't do what I needed! I don't want to download anything else! Just copy the code from your answer!

Comment: "Just copy the code from your answer!" bad idea to write this here

Comment: Maybe by printing backspaces, which can be done form batch files: http://superuser.com/questions/82929/how-to-overwrite-the-same-line-in-command-output-from-batch-file

Comment: Please elaborate on how a video of three dots appearing on the screen is simultaneously what you want and don't want.

Comment: Please stop downvoting this question.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [How to overwrite the same line in command output from batch file](https://superuser.com/q/82929/241386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define CR to contain a carriage return (0x0D)
for /f %%A in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%A"

<nul set/p"=[*............]!CR!"
pause >nul
<nul set/p"=[**...........]!CR!"
pause >nul
<nul set/p"=[***..........]!CR!"
pause >nul
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367518/is-it-possible-to-echo-some-non-printable-characters-in-batch-cmd)