# Batch echo on same line to .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a project where I want to print several things to one line in a .txt file with multiple echo statements. For example I would want this:

```
 echo A
 echo B
```

To end up looking like this:

```
  AB
```

Instead of this:

```
  A
  B
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `set /p` trick to output without a new line character.

```
>>file.txt (
    set /p "=A" <nul
    set /p "=B" <nul
)
```

You don't need to encase the statements in parenthesis, you can have them on separate lines if need be.

```
set /p "=A" <nul >>file.txt
REM Some thing that you don't want to output to file.txt
set /p "=B" <nul >>file.txt
```