# Batch file - check if command is available

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a small batch file in windows that needs to run a nodejs app. Before running the app I need to make sure that node is installed by the user, and if not show him a message that node is required.

What I did is this:

```
@echo OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Check if node is installed
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('node -v') do set output=%%i

IF "!output!" EQU "" (
    echo node could not be found
) else (
    node %~dp0app.js
)
```

If the user has node installed then `output` will contain the version number. If not installed then it will be empty. This logic works. But if node is not installed (`node -v` command not found), the batch result also shows the following output:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node could not be found
```

I would like to hide the "not recognized" message from the user and just show "node could not be found".

How can I hide it?

Comment: cmd shell returns 9009 for %ERRORLEVEL% when a command doesn't exist.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091906/official-ms-reference-for-cmd-exe-errorlevel-9009.  No time to leave full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to suppress the errormessage, redirect it to NUL:

```
set "output=not installed"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('node -v 2^>nul') do set output=%%i
echo %output%
```

another way (inspired by Npocmaka's answer):

```
where node.exe >nul 2>&1 && echo installed || echo not installed
```

or to keep closer to your original output:

```
where node.exe >nul 2>&1 && node %~dp0app.js || echo node could not be found
```

Comment: (upvote)I forgot about `where` , though the command is not available on XP and some Win2003 installations.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this errorlevel check to test specifically for 9009, which is the return code for the program not found.

`if "%errorlevel%" == "9009"`

For your example this would work:

```
@echo OFF
REM Check if node is installed
node -v 2> Nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "9009" (
    echo node could not be found
) else (
    node %~dp0app.js
)
```

Comment: thanks. this seems to do the trick but if node is installed it types the version number from running the command - i want to hide that as well. so it would be just a check if node exist (then run it) if not show message - transparent to the user.

Comment: @developer82 Then change the line `node -v 2> Nul` to `node -v >Nul 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is to check if the executable is presented in the path or in the local directory:

```
set "status=not installed"

if exist "./node.exe" (
    set "status=installed"
)

for %%# in (node.exe) do  if not "%%~f$PATH:#" equ "" set "status=installed"

echo %status%

if "%status%" equ "installed" (
   node %~dp0app.js
)
```

for the `%%~f$PATH` check `FOR /?`

---

Since windows 7 you have also the `where` command:

```
where node || (
 echo node is not installed
)
```

Comment: Isn't `Set MyPath=.;%PAth%` followed by `for %%# in (node.exe) do  if "%%~f$MyPATH:#" Neq "" set "status=installed"` a bit simpler?

Comment: @LotPings - yes it is :-)