# How to run Python Script from node js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, windows, spawn

I have an api in node js in which I am trying to execute the python Script

My Directory structure is as below

```
 Nodejs_application
    index.js

 Python_application
    script1.py
```

I just have `print("Hello World")` in my `script1.py`

I have tried the below code in node js to run the python script

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

var dataToSend;
 // spawn new child process to call the python script
 const python = spawn('python', [__dirname+'../../../../pythoncode/script1.py']);
 // collect data from script
 python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
  dataToSend = data.toString();
 });
 // in close event we are sure that stream from child process is closed
 python.on('close', (code) => {
 console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
 // send data to browser
 res.send(dataToSend)   
 });
```

I am getting `code 9009` error. Where did I go wrong?

Alternative code which I tried

```
  const {PythonShell} =require('python-shell');
  
  let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    //  scriptPath: 'path/to/my/scripts', //If you are having python_test.py script in same folder, then it's optional.
   // args: ['shubhamk314'] //An argument which can be accessed in the script using sys.argv[1]
};
 

PythonShell.run('script1.py', options, function (err, result){
      if (err) throw err;
      // result is an array consisting of messages collected
      //during execution of script.
      console.log('result: ', result.toString());
      res.send(result.toString())
});
```

Error I am getting is

```
 PythonShellError: Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from
```

Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

In CMD I have given "python", I am getting

```
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct 4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Is this a Windows system?

Comment: @jabaa Yes it is a windows system

Comment: Do you use CMD or PowerShell? 9009 is the CMD error code for "command not found": [Official MS reference for cmd.exe %errorlevel% 9009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091906/official-ms-reference-for-cmd-exe-errorlevel-9009) Can you start Python with `python` in your CMD? Did you set the path in your environment variables?

Comment: I use CMD. What is the command missing

Comment: What happens when you open a new CMD window and type `python`? Do you get the error message `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` or do you get a Python REPL? Did you set the path to the Python executable in your environment variables?

Comment: No I didnt set in environment variables. How to set it?. Actually I have zero knowledge on python. And in CMD I have given "python", I am getting "Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information."

Comment: It seems like the Python path is already set. I can't help here. I have no Windows system at hand and no experience with this.

Comment: I have edited my question I tried with "python-shell", even that is giving me error which I have shared in the question

Comment: @RajithaGanjiIN Have you python installed?! What does `python --version` output?

Comment: @Marc Python 3.10.0 is installed. It was in a comment. I added it to the question.

Comment: The only two options I could think of are, 1) the Python path is not set in your environment variables (can you start it from everywhere?) and 2) your environment variables aren't read by `spawn` call.

Comment: I dont access to see the environmental variable is there a way to give the path from code?

Comment: Of course, you can set full path. Replace `spawn('python'` with `spawn('Z:\full\path\to\bin\python'`

Comment: @jabaa I tried with the path, I am getting the error as "ganji002AppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython310 ENOENT". Why is my path getting displayed without backslash in the error

Comment: You need double backslashes `\\ ` or slashes `/`

Comment: It is giving me the same ENOENT errno:-4058 for the path "C:/Users/rrrr002/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310"

Comment: Do you have a file `C:/Users/rrrr002/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310` without extension? What is the result of `dir C:/Users/rrrr002/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310`?

Comment: @jabaa I didnt understand, what do you mean by without extension?

Comment: @jabaa I have python.exe and pythonw.exe inside "C:/Users/rrrr002/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310"

Comment: Why did you call `C:/Users/rrrr002/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310` then? You can't run a directory. You have to run an executable.

Comment: @jabaa So I have to call "C:/Users/rrrr002/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe"?

Comment: Why didn't you try it instead of asking?

Comment: @jabaa I have tried it, its working. Thanks alot.

Comment: Why do you use `'../pythoncode/script1.py'` instead of `"C:\IWA\local\project\pythoncode\script1.py"`?

Comment: @jabaa because the path of the python script is specific to the node directory, and not specific fo the drive

Comment: @jabaa Do you have idea of streams? if so can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71324909/read-mth-row-to-nth-row-from-a-buffer-data-in-node-js

Comment: @jabaa I tried the above code in different environment. It is giving me the error 
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.3)

Comment: When I try to install pandas it is givng me the above error. But in nodejs it is giving
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: Anaconda has its own Python executable and libraries. `C:/Users/rrrr002/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe` doesn't use `c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`. Either use the Python executable from Anaconda or install pandas for the other Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are not providing the correct python path and python is not configured on your path and hence not recognized as 'python'.

take a look at:

- C:\Python36
- C:\Users(Your logged in User)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

or try running:

```
where python
```

in order to get full path.

additionally i would recommend you to use a package for running your script.

you can check this package on npm- [native-python](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@guydev/native-python)

it provides a very simple and powerful way to run python functions from node
might solve your problem.
import { runFunction } from '@guydev/native-python'

```
const example = async () => {
   const input = [1,[1,2,3],{'foo':'bar'}]
   const { error, data } = await runFunction('/path/to/file.py','hello_world', '/path/to/python', input)

   // error will be null if no error occured.
   if (error) {
       console.log('Error: ', error)
   }

   else {
       console.log('Success: ', data)
       // prints data or null if function has no return value
   }
}
```

python module

```
# module: file.py

def hello_world(a,b,c):
    print( type(a), a) 
    # <class 'int'>, 1

    print(type(b),b)
    # <class 'list'>, [1,2,3]

    print(type(c),c)
    # <class 'dict'>, {'foo':'bar'}
```

Comment: It looks like you are promoting your own work. [Please see the instructions on self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): "_you **must** disclose your affiliation in your post._"