# Read mth row to nth row from a buffer data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs, event-stream

I am getting a large file data in chunks from frontend. The format of this data is base64.

As the file is too large I need to read or convert this base64 format to any other format if required and send only 1000 records at a time as a response to the frontend. So, first we need to save this base64 data somewhere and whenever a request comes from frontend i.e, the request could be asking for 1001 - 2000 records or 45001 - 46000 records, I need to send back those particular rows as a response to frontend in json format.

How can I fetch a particular rows like mth - nth?

This is my router file, where I am using `multer`

```
 const express = require("express");
 const router = express.Router();
 var multer  = require('multer')();
 const uploadDocument = require("./RA/UploadDocument")

 router.post("/uploadDocument", multer.single('slicedFile'), uploadDocument)
```

Below is the uploadDocument file where I have concatenated the chunks received from frontend

```
 const XLSX = require('xlsx') 
 var buffer = [];
      buffer.push(req.file.buffer);
    if(req.body.isLastBlob==='true'){
        let buf = Buffer.concat(buffer);
        var base64 = (buf.toString('base64'));
        var pre="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,";
        base64 = pre+base64;
        buffer = [];  

        var docdata = base64.split(',').pop();
        var bufdata = Buffer.from(docdata, 'base64');
          let wb= XLSX.read(bufdata, {type: "buffer", sheetRows: 100});
          const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
          const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
          const exceldata = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
        console.log(exceldata)
    }
```

Consider this is my excel file

```
PlatformName    SerialNo    ICC_Serial_No
IS20    4520863450  9018229990
IS20    9965713930  7648298200
IS20    7365206700  4787377990
IS20    8417755210  2335387030
IS20    6499775990  811401940
IS20    3329719760  2241961760
IS20    540691670   4210369020
IS20    4805607930  6071220080
IS20    3537648760  5137843290
```

When there are upto 50000 records of such rows it is giving me proper output similar to below for `console.log(exceldata)`

```
 [
  {
    'PlatformName': 'IS20',
    'SerialNo': 4520863450,
    'ICC_Serial_No': 9018229990
  },
  {
    'PlatformName': 'IS20',
    'SerialNo': 4520863450,
    'ICC_Serial_No': 9018229990
  },
  {
    'PlatformName': 'IS20',
    'SerialNo': 4520863450,
    'ICC_Serial_No': 9018229990
    },
    ...... more 49080 rows
  ]
```

But when I upload huge file which have around 1000000 records it is giving me output similar to

```
 [
  {
    '0': 'IS20',
    '1': 4520863450,
      __EMPTY: 'SAF',
  },
  {
    'IS20': '9018229990',
    '9018229990': 4520863450,
    __EMPTY: 'SAF',
  },
  {
    __EMPTY: 'SAF',
     __EMPTY_2: 'Subscription fees',
    'IS20': 9018229990
    }
  ]
```

How can I fetch a particular rows like mth - nth and send it back to frontend as a response every time it is asked for passing the m and n in the request?
Please help

Comment: Store the data in a database.

Comment: ok, but if I want to get the rows between 2001 to 3000, how can I read it from a buffer or base64?

Comment: @jabaa Basically this buffer data is the data of a huge file, so a file is uploaded from frontend and a base64/buffer data is passed to node. I need to send 1000 records immediately after file upload, then later when pagination is clicked I need to send that particular 1000 records based on the page selected. For this functionality I have to send only particular rows from the buffer data

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the database. Store the data in a database. Read the data from database and send it back as JSON. You can query the rows and columns you need.

Comment: Even if we can do that, how can we save a huge file which has 100000 records without breaking the server.

Comment: 100000 records is nothing for a database. I don't understand why you're so focused on this _"file"_ part.

Comment: Also, before that I need to pass the headers of that file to frontend immediately after the file is uploaded. Then later I need to save the data into database

Comment: @jabaa but it is taking huge time

Comment: And you think searching, reading and writing files will be faster? You can be sure that DBMS will handle this more efficient.

Comment: Ye, DBMS should handle more efficiently than javascript. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @jabaa i need to read the header and return first 100 rows from the buffer data. and when I try to read from the buffer data of huge files, I am getting incorrect headers

Comment: Where is the code that reads incorrect headers? Please provide a [mcve] and focus on one problem.

Comment: @jabaa I have added sample data and the output of bot small file and large file in the question above

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your problem. Send the file to the backend. Read the file. Send a response. Store data in a database. Read data from database for each request. You can use a cache like Redis. Where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: A file is uploaded in frontend and the filedata is converted to buffer format and is sent through API to backend. in the backend I am trying to get the first 100 records from the buffer data to send back as a response. For which I have used XLSX module. Hence I have used "sheetRows: 100" to read only first 100 records

Comment: The above code is working perfectly fine for small files, whereas if I upload huge files I am getting incorrect json. If you notice the first json is the output of small files, which has a perfect key value pair. Key is the heading name  and value is the data of that column. Whereas, the second json is the output of large files, the keys you notice are not the headings of the excel data

Comment: Where is the code that creates the JSON for the response? Please provide a [mcve] and debugging details.