# Append Echo on earlier Echo

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to be able to concat a new ECHO message to a prior ECHO message, something like this:

Command:

```
ECHO PROCESSING...
REM some process here
ECHO DONE
```

Result:

```
PROCESSING...
DONE
```

What I want as a result is this

```
PROCESSING...DONE
```

I will first echo the "PROCESSING..." message, and then after my process is done, I would like to be able to append the "DONE" message at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an undocumented use of the set /p command:

```
@echo off
set /p =PROCESSING... <nul
REM some process here
ECHO DONE
pause
```

Comment: This will only work if your processes between the `set` command and the `echo` command do not output anything.  This is still pretty clever