# Disable newline after ECHO command in Batch

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I have a batch file that does the following to write to a file:

```
echo @echo off> start.bat
echo cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BukkitServer>> start.bat
echo java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true>> start.bat
```

The only problem is that it adds one blank line to the end of the file "start.bat". I am wondering how to remove that empty line from within the same batch file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)

Comment: What is the purpose of this dynamic generation (vs. keeping a static copy around)? The main difference I can see is that since the first script evaluates `%USERPROFILE%`, the second script could stop working if the actual value of `%USERPROFILE%` changes later.

Comment: it doesn't add a blank line. It only ends the last line with <CR><LF> - as every other line. What's your problem with this?

Comment: Are you satisfied by the given answer? If so, please mark it as accepted (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or leave a comment to tell us what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
echo @echo off> start.bat
echo cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BukkitServer>> start.bat
echo|set /p="java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true">> start.bat
```

I have simply replaced the last `echo` with `echo|set /p=` to avoid the new line at the end.

Or you could also use, for the last line:

```
<nul set /p =java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true>> start.bat
```

You will get the same result here but it seems to be more robust for other cases (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7105690/1149528)

Comment: Why this downvote? Doesn't this code work? I've tested it and it works for me (Win7)...

Comment: works for me on my MBP - and with no comments I'm balancing out the down vote output: `@echo off
cd %USERPROFILE%DesktopBukkitServer`

Comment: It replaces the new line with a space when I do this.

Comment: @snuggles08 You're right, I have fixed my answer: you should use quotes (") around your last line: `/p="....">>`

Comment: @snuggles08 Are you satisfied by the given answer? If so, please mark it as accepted (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or leave a comment to tell us what is wrong.

Comment: @xav Done! (insert random filler text here so I can post)