# Clear a line/move the cursor, using the Timeout command or similar

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was trying to find a way to clear (CLS) a single line (see [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972249/cls-clear-a-single-line/11972796)), but found that the solutions, which involved moving the cursor, required extra software or modifications to files, which is not ideal.

However, I later noticed that the TIMEOUT command actually moves the cursor, which can be demonstrated with the following code:

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Notice how the cursor moves to the number.
ECHO Press [Ctrl]+[C] for an interesting result.
PAUSE
ECHO(
TIMEOUT 99999
PAUSE
```

If Ctrl+C is pressed after a couple of seconds, the "Terminate Batch Job" prompt overwrites the TIMEOUT output after the number. Any typing also continues to overwrite it.

What I am looking for, is any way to clear a line, change the line, or move the cursor somewhere, and also anything similar that could be useful. (I know this is a bit vague)

---

One idea was if it was possible to modify the stdout in such a way that the cursor still moved, it would at least be possible to get a changing number at one point in a custom line.

It might also be possible to asynchronously do both TIMEOUT and ECHO commands to have a similar effect to Ctrl+C.

---

Redirecting the TIMEOUT stdout to nul gives no LF character. This in conjunction with:

```
<nul SET /P var=#
    REM echo without a LF character
```

...Could possibly be used to create progress bars.

---

Any thoughts, ideas, or other commands with similar effects are welcome.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25774286/2861476) could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using answers from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/82929/how-to-overwrite-the-same-line-in-command-output-from-batch-file) you can have an increasing number printed.

It is important to insert the backspace character in place of **insert_baskspace_here** below.

You will need an editor that supports insertion of ASCII characters.  I used Ultraedit but Notepad++ works too.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set BS=insert_baskspace_here

Echo I printed 1 time
set /p "=I printed 2 times" <NUL

for /L %%I in (3,1,9) DO (
  timeout /t 1 > nul
  set /p "=!BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!%%I times" <NUL
)
```

The output starts as:

```
I printed 1 time
I printed 2 times
```

It changes each second and finishes with:

```
I printed 1 time
I printed 9 times
```

A few changes and you have a little progress spinner wheel:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set BS=

set /p "=Processing.../" <NUL

for /L %%J in (0,1,9) DO (
  for %%I in (-,\,^|,/,) DO (
    timeout /t 1 > nul
    set /p "=!BS!%%I" <NUL
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Great technique, though it doesn't seem to handle lines that are long enough to wrap around very well (but this might not be possible).

Comment: Correct, as far as I know it is not possible to make the cursor backspace up a line.

Comment: Maybe other control characters can work/help/have effects. [This site](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) has some info on the functions/purposes of control characters.