# Python input blocked when called from batch within an "if" and after a "timeout"

Tags: python, batch-file

Minimum working example:

test.bat:

```
@echo off
if 0==0 (
  timeout 3
  python test.py
)
```

test.py:

```
input('press ENTER to exit')
```

In cmd.exe:

```
call test.bat
> Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
> press ENTER to exit_
```

Then it's stuck at the input statement. If I keep pressing enter, it will eventually raise an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    input('press ENTER to exit')
OSError: [WinError 8] Not enough storage is available to process this command
```

I'm on Windows 7 SP1, tried it with

- Python 3.6 (64-bit)
- Python 3.6 (32-bit)
- Python 3.5 (32-bit)
- Python 2.7 (32-bit) (in this case it's stuck forever without raising exception)

Can anyone reproduce this and/or have any idea where it went wrong?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that (Windows 7, Python 2.7), but I have no idea what is the cause. I believe `timeout` is messing around with the _stdin_ (`0`) handle. What happens when you try adding `<&3 3< nul` to the `timeout` command line?

Comment: Forget about the redirection thing `<&3 3< nul`, this has nothing to do with the code at hand -- sorry for confusion! Nevertheless, I found out that the `if` command may be removed, but the problem remains as long as the parentheses stay (or the two command lines are concatenated by `&`). As soon as `timeout` is replaced by `pause` (which reads from *std_in* too), everything works as expected. By the way, I can reproduce the problem also on Windows 7 with Python 2.6, but I can't on Windows 10 (with Python 2.7)...

Comment: are you asking why this bug exists, or how you can overcome it?

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard   Both, I guess?

Comment: please do me a favour, open regedit, goto `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems` the is a `Windows` value. Open it and scroll to the right until you find something like `SharedSection=1024,2048,256` and let me know what this value is.

Comment: I found `SharedSection=1024,20480,768`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on Windows 7 with Python 3.6.5 64 bit.

A couple of alternatives to avoid the issue with `timeout`:

```
@echo off
if 0==0 (
  echo Pause for 3 seconds
  ping -n 3 localhost >nul
  python test.py
)
exit /b
```

This uses `ping` which causes no issue.

```
@echo off
if 0==0 (
  timeout 3
  call :run_python test.py
)
exit /b

:run_python
python %*
exit /b
```

This uses a label named `:run_python` which allows the interpreter to run Python outside the context of the parentheses. Any arguments passed following the called label will be passed to `python`.

Comment: To wait for 3 seconds you actually need `ping -n 4` to have 4 attempts and three pause intervals...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can reproduce the behavour you observed on Windows 7 with Python 2.6 and Python 2.7, but not on Windows 10 with Python 2.7. The file sizes of `timeout.exe` differ between Windows 7 and Windows 10, so there have been changes to that command.

I believe that `timeout` messes around with the file pointer in the *STD_IN* stream (handle `0`), particularly because it moves the pointer for displaying the seconds countdown (see this thread: [Clear a line/move the cursor, using the Timeout command or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31259448)).

The problem does not only occur together with the `if` command, it comes up as soon as `timeout` and the Python script call are in the same parenthesised block of code:

```cmd
(
    timeout 3
    python test.py
)
```

The same issue happens when they are in the same line:

```cmd
timeout 3 & python test.py
```

When the two command lines are in separate lines without parentheses, it works fine:

```cmd
timeout 3
python test.py
```

As soon as the `timeout` command is replaced by `pause`, which also reads from *STD_IN*, everything works as expected:

```cmd
(
    pause
    python test.py
)
```

Or also:

```cmd
pause & python test.py
```

[michael_heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9012170) already provided a nice work-around in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520198) using `ping`. However, this cannot be aborted by a key-press like `timeout` (so it is actually equivalent to `timeout 3 /NOBREAK`).