# How do I end an echo string in Batchfile?

Tags: string, batch-file, echo

I'm trying to created a Batch program that has multiple `echo` commands and `if` commands in one line. The problem is when I type a command after an `echo` command, it thinks it's part of the `echo` string and prints it to the screen instead of executing it.

For example:

`if %var1% == 1 echo %var2% (right here I need to end the echo) if %var3% == 1 echo %var4%`

`echo.`

`if %var5% == 1 echo %var6% (right here I need to end the echo) if %var7% == 1 echo %var8%`

I'm sure it's fairly simple, but I need to know if there's some character or command that will end a line without being interpreted as part of the message. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be easier to use the if statements to build up what the echo is with set statements, and then echo it on the line after or at the very end. It looks like you are trying to concatenate strings/variables together based upon your if and then echo the result.

Comment: the example wasn't necessarily what I'm trying to do. But I'm sure there's a way to end an echo string. Do you know what it is?

Comment: I don't, but this SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7105690/1439998) may have insight for you.

Comment: This is useful, but it doesn't exactly answer my question. Using this method wouldn't help me add a new command after the string would it?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't tried playing around with it. I leave that to you. :)

Comment: @MartinNoreke - A `|` isn't going to really help here, since it's just used to pass the output of the command on the left as the input of the command on the right.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you absolutely _must_ have all of the `if` statements on the same line? Having each `if` on its own separate line would completely solve the problem.

Comment: `(if %var1% == 1 echo %var2%) & if %var3% == 1 echo %var4%`

Comment: @SomethingDark I had a plan for something, but now I realize that it won't work even if I do have a solution to this issue. I still want to know how to do it though. I need them on this same line so the echo lines will be fluid. Think of it like a sentence that stops as soon as a certain requirement isn't met. Each `if` is a condition that decides if it will echo or go to the next line.

Comment: `if %var1% == 1 (echo %var2% ) else ( if %var3% == 1 echo %var4%)`

Comment: @JosefZ I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I want it to do both, not just one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a string without a linefeed. `echo`won't to that. Instead you can use this workaround:

```
<nul set /p"=first "
<nul set /p"=second "
echo third
```

for your example:

```
if %var1% == 1 <nul set /p=%var2% 
if %var3% == 1 echo %var4%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use && to separate pieces of code:

```
if %Var1% equ 12 echo %Var1% && if %Var2% neq 12 echo %Var2%
```

I tested it, it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If the first `if` is not true, the second one is not even executed. You need to enclose the whole first `if` in parentheses, as I did in my comment above...

Comment: Test this: `set Var1=ABC` - `set Var2=XYZ` - `if %Var1% equ 12 echo %Var1% && if %Var2% neq 12 echo %Var2%`. It should show "XYZ" because Var2 is not 12, but show nothing instead...

Answer (score 0):

I posted this answer here because it seems that my previous comment go unnoticed.

Usually an `&` is used to separate several *individual commands* in the same line; however, if the `&` is placed after an `if` or `for` (in the same line), then the `&` *groups* all commands in the same `if` or `for`. If you want to put several *individual* `if` or `for` commands (in the same line), you need to *isolate* each one enclosing they in parentheses:

```
(if %var1% == 1 echo %var2%) & if %var3% == 1 echo %var4%
(if %var5% == 1 echo %var6%) & (if %var7% == 1 echo %var8%) & echo After two previous if's
(if %varX% == 1 echo This one & echo This also) & echo Independently of previous if
```