# Echo to a file without trailing a line break (batch)

Tags: batch-file, line

I am having a problem with my life creator program.
It simply chooses random numbers that stand for something and puts it together.
(I have tried combining variables)
here is the code:

```
@set num=1
@SET /A a=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
@if %a% == 10 set life%num%= ----
@if %a% == 9 set life%num%=O
@if %a% == 8 set life%num%=^
@if %a% == 7 set life%num%=%
@if %a% == 6 set life%num%=#
@if %a% == 5 set life%num%=@
@if %a% == 4 set life%num%=)
@if %a% == 3 set life%num%=()
@if %a% == 2 set life%num%=~
@if %a% == 1 set life%num%=OO
@echo %a% >"gencode".txt
@set num=2
@SET /A a=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
@if %a% == 10 set life%num%=----
@if %a% == 9 set life%num%=O
@if %a% == 8 set life%num%=^
@if %a% == 7 set life%num%=%
@if %a% == 6 set life%num%=#
@if %a% == 5 set life%num%=@
@if %a% == 4 set life%num%=)
@if %a% == 3 set life%num%=()
@if %a% == 2 set life%num%=~
@if %a% == 1 set life%num%=OO
@set life3= %life1%-%life2%
@echo %life3%>"lifeform".txt
@echo %a% >>"gencode".txt
```

and here is the variable putter together thing:

```
@set final= 500
@set /a pass= %pass% + 1
@set /a cnum= %cnum% + 1
@set counterold=%counter%
@set life%cnum%-%counter%= %a%-%b%
@if %pass% == 1 goto start
:repeat
@if %ficnum% == 500 goto final
@set life2%cnum%-%counter%= life%counterold%-life%counter%
@set life2%cnum%-%counterold%= life%counterold%-life%counter%
@set /a ficnum= %ficnum% + 1
@set life3%ficnum%-%counter%= life2%counterold%-life2%counter%
@goto repeat
:final
@set /a final= %final% + 1
@set /a counter= %counter% + 1
@set /a ficnum= %ficnum% + 1
@set counter1= %counter%
@set ficnum1= %ficnum%
:finalst
@set /a final= %final% - 1
@set /a counter1= %counter1% - 1
@set /a ficnum= %ficnum% - 1
@set /a ficnum1= %ficnum1% - 1
@set /a counter= %counter% - 1
@set final%final%=%life3%%ficnum%-%counter%-%life3%%ficnum1%-%counter1%
@if %final% == 0 goto finalend
@goto finalst
:finalend
@echo final0>"lifeform".txt
```

So I would like to know, (INSTEAD OF JUST COMBINING EACH VARIABLE TO ONE AND ECHOING THAT TO ONE LINE) how do I set a line to write to so I can just write each variable to one line, creating the life-form.
I am asking this because every time I echo something it goes down 1 line in the text file.

And here is an experimental version of the life creator:

```
@set num1=1
:repeat
@if %counter% == 500 exit
@set  /a num1= %num1% + 1
@SET /A a=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
@if %a% == 10 set life%num%=----
@if %a% == 9 set life%num%=O
@if %a% == 8 set life%num%=^
@if %a% == 7 set life%num%=%
@if %a% == 6 set life%num%=#
@if %a% == 5 set life%num%=@
@if %a% == 4 set life%num%=)
@if %a% == 3 set life%num%=()
@if %a% == 2 set life%num%=~
@if %a% == 1 set life%num%=OO
@echo %a% >>"gencode".txt
@set /a num2= %num% + 1
@SET /A a=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
@if %a% == 10 set life%num%=----
@if %a% == 9 set life%num%=O
@if %a% == 8 set life%num%=^
@if %a% == 7 set life%num%=%
@if %a% == 6 set life%num%=#
@if %a% == 5 set life%num%=@
@if %a% == 4 set life%num%=)
@if %a% == 3 set life%num%=()
@if %a% == 2 set life%num%=~
@if %a% == 1 set life%num%=OO
@set final= 500
@set /a pass= %pass% + 1
@set /a cnum= %cnum% + 1
@set counterold=%counter%
@set life%cnum%-%counter%= %a%-%b%
@if %pass% == 1 goto start
:repeat
@if %ficnum% == 500 goto final
@set life2%cnum%-%counter%= life%counterold%-life%counter%
@set life2%cnum%-%counterold%= life%counterold%-life%counter%
@set /a ficnum= %ficnum% + 1
@set life3%ficnum%-%counter%= life2%counterold%-life2%counter%
@goto repeat
:final
@set /a final= %final% + 1
@set /a counter= %counter% + 1
@set /a ficnum= %ficnum% + 1
@set counter1= %counter%
@set ficnum1= %ficnum%
:finalst
@set /a final= %final% - 1
@set /a counter1= %counter1% - 1
@set /a ficnum= %ficnum% - 1
@set /a ficnum1= %ficnum1% - 1
@set /a counter= %counter% - 1
@set final%final%=%life3%%ficnum%-%counter%-%life3%%ficnum1%-%counter1%
@if %final% == 0 goto finalend
@goto finalst
:finalend
@echo final0>"lifeform".txt
```

Comment: Do you know that a space after `=` in `set var=` goes into the variable? To debug what's happening remove all `@` and look at the output.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Generally, yes, but that doesn't apply to `set /a` - any whitespace is trimmed from the result of a calculation; similarly, whitespace is ignored if you use the _numerical_ comparison operators such as `EQU`.

Comment: If you want none of your script lines echoed, just use `@echo off` as the 1st line, then you don't have to prefix each line with `@`.

Comment: @mklement0, I specifically wrote `set var=`, not `set /a var=`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - there's a lot of "noise" in your question. Can you boil this down to a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @wOxxOm: Good. Now we have both cases covered.

Comment: What I am saying is: Instead of combining each variable into one and then putting that in a text file, I want to just set the line, so I can echo each that variable to one line.

Comment: @TheBeastprogrammer: I still don't get it, but perhaps others will. However, please add any clarifications _directly to the answer_ - not in comments. Also, if you're addressing someone specifically and you want them notified of your comment, @-mention them, as I've done here.

Comment: @mklement0: First off I have edited the question. Second off here is an explanation for you. Every time you use batch to write something to a text file it goes down one line, So I tried combining all of the variables I needed to write into 1 variable, So it can be on 1 line. I am asking this so I can find out how to echo each variable to 1 line.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>**Update**: To output to a *file*, as now reflected in the question title, *no* special considerations apply (use the usual output redirections), which ultimately makes this question a duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433/45375).</sup>

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to **echo (print to stdout) a string without a trailing line break.**

`cmd.exe`'s `echo` does *not* allow you to do that, but there's a **workaround**:

```sh
 set "var=world"
 <NUL set /p ="Hello, %var%: "
 <NUL set /p ="Still on the same line. "
 echo Still on the same line, but ending it now.
```

This outputs the following, single line:

```
Hello, world: Still on the same line. Still on the same line, but ending it now.
```

**Caveat** re **error level**: The `<NUL set /p ...` trick sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to `1`; in order to explicitly reset it to `0`, use a dummy command such as `ver >NUL`.

There are **limitations**:

- The **string mustn't contain `"` chars.** - while you can *double* them to avoid a syntax error, they will then appear doubled in the output too.
- The **string's first non-whitespace character mustn't be a `=`** - whether as a literal or as the result of variable expansion.

  - `<nul set /p ="=foo"` and `<nul set /p ==foo` inexplicably cause a *syntax error*(!).
  - (`<nul set /p =^=foo` also causes a syntax error and `<nul set "/p==foo"` would actually be interpreted as non-interactively setting variable `/p` to value `=foo`and thus produces *no output* at all.)
- **Leading tabs and spaces are stripped** from the string.
- Note that if you don't double-quote the string, the command will break if the string contains shell metacharacters such as `&` and `|`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468559/45375) may provide a robust solution to handle all these edge cases, although it does require an aux. batch file.

---

**How it works:**

`set /p <varName>=<value>` is designed to *prompt* the user for a variable value, by reading a line from stdin, using `<value>` as the *prompt string* to print *inline*; try it with `set "/pFOO=Enter FOO: "`

Something like `<NUL set /p ="..."` then uses this inline printing of the prompt string while suppressing the interactive prompt (by providing stdin input from the `NUL` device (`<NUL`, which causes `set /p` to return instantly, because there's nothing to read).

Note how `/p ="..."` contains no variable name before the `=`, given that we're not interested in assigning to a variable here - `set` is luckily fine with that (you *may* use a dummy variable name - e.g., `/p UNUSED="..."`, but note that you may inadvertently overwrite an existing variable by that name; also, using a variable name does *not* help the syntax-error issue with a string with a leading `=`.

Comment: Thanks! Alot, Just could you explain how it works?  Also, Will it work in a loop?

Comment: Sorry, I just did try it, and sorry, I meant to write to a file with it....

Comment: @TheBeastprogrammer: That should be fine - just make sure you never use `echo` - use `<NUL set /p="..." >>file` for all output.

Comment: One more question, would it work in a loop?

Comment: @TheBeastprogrammer: Yes, just be sure to use `>>` (and make sure that any pre-existing output file is deleted at the beginning).

Comment: I keep getting the error: The process cant access the file because it is being used in another process? - when I am using it in a loop.

Comment: @TheBeastprogrammer: What does the loop look like, _exactly_?

Comment: I don't know what you mean?

Comment: @TheBeastprogrammer: Based on what I saw before you removed the code from your comment (comment are at best suited for a _single_ line of code, enclosed in backticks for formatting): Your output line must look like this: `<NUL set /p=%a% >>"lifeform".txt` - note the `<NUL ` at the beginning and the mandatory space before `>>`.

Comment: For instance `for /L %G in (1,1,3) do <nul set /p="Hello, %var%: ">>foo.txt` loop works as expected (in batch script use `%%G` instead of `%G`)

Comment: @mklement0: Okay, the error stopped for some reason, but the output file has the stuff it should have then, has random pieces of code in it.

Comment: @TheBeastprogrammer: I don't think the remaining problem is connected to use of `<NUL set /p=...` - try without redirection to a file to see what's going on. If you can't solve the problem, ask a _new_ question with a _minimal_ example that doesn't work.