# Inconsistent string encryption result between program and Shell

Tags: c++, c, powershell, openssl

I've wrote the below code snippet that passes a string to openssl by echo'ing, using popen; however the result is different than if I manually pass the arguments in PowerShell.  Any help is appreciated...

```
void encrypt_message(const char * message_in, char * encrypted_return)
{
    char encryption_cmd[1024] = { '\0' };
    strcat(encryption_cmd, "echo '");
    strcat(encryption_cmd, message_in);
    strcat(encryption_cmd, "' | openssl.exe dgst -sha256 -hmac ");
    strcat(encryption_cmd, SEC_KEY);

    printf("CMD= %s\n",encryption_cmd);

    char   psBuffer[1024] = { '\0' };
    FILE   *pPipe;

    if ((pPipe = _popen(encryption_cmd, "rt")) == NULL)
        return;

    while (fgets(psBuffer, 1024, pPipe));
        
    if (!feof(pPipe))
        printf("Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");

    sscanf(psBuffer, "(stdin)= %s", encrypted_return);

    printf("RESULT= %s\n",encrypted_return);
}
```

**This is the output of the function:**
[image]

**However when I manually invoke in PowerShell I get a different result**
[image]

It looks as if popen is sprinkling something in that openssl is interpretting, yielding a different result.  But I can't narrow what exactly! Thanks

**UPDATE:**  I get the same result as my program code when I pass arguments in cmd.exe instead of PowerShell.... so it appears it's PowerShell that is doing something strange.
[image]

Comment: Is unicode active?

Comment: it's not........

Comment: Okay I actually just passed argument in cmd.exe instead and get the same result  as my program code.  I don't know why PowerShell is giving something different?

Comment: Looks like `cmd`'s `echo` is outputting including the quotes. PowerShell is not including the quotes

Comment: Doing different quote/no-quote combinations across cmd/PowerShell I still can not get the same result between shells.

Comment: So it seem to be inconsistent, perhaps about whitespaces as well. Not sure if you can rely on anything here.

Comment: What if you drop the echo part from the powershell example.

Comment: And/or try `"'this'"` so it's actually being passed with the single quotes to openssl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`echo 'this'`  does different things in `cmd.exe` vs. PowerShell**:

- In `cmd.exe`, the command output is verbatim string `'this'` , including the single quotes and the trailing space, *plus a trailing newline*.

  - Unfortunately, `cmd.exe`'s `echo` echoes any quoting *as specified*; generally `cmd.exe` does *not* understand *single*-quoting (`'...'`); while it *does* understand *double*-quoting (`"..."`), and while this double-quoting is necessary to protect metacharacters such as `&`, `echo` still echoes them (instead of *stripping* them, which you'd expect for quotes that *syntactic* function).
- In PowerShell, where `echo` is simply a built-in alias for the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet, the command output is verbatim string `this` - the syntactic quotes are stripped, and the trailing space is irrelevant - *plus a trailing newline*.

  - PowerShell understands both `'...'` strings (verbatim) and `"..."` (expandable, i.e. interpolating), and properly strips quotes with syntactic function; for more information about string literals in PowerShell, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375).

There is no single `echo`-based command that would work the same in both shells.

**If it's acceptable to append a trailing newline:**

As stated, in effect, `echo` invariably results in a trailing newline getting appended to the string being echoed.

- In `cmd.exe`, pass the string *unquoted* and *immediately* follow it with `|`:

  - `echo this| openssl.exe ...`
  - if the string contains `cmd.exe` metacharacters, such as `&` or `;`, `^`-escape them.
- In PowerShell, while `echo 'this'` works, you can simply omit the `echo` and rely on PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior:

  - `'this' | openssl.exe ...`
  - If the string has *embedded* `'` chars., escape them as `''`.

**If it's *not* acceptable to append a trailing newline:**

- In `cmd.exe`, you have to **resort to a *hack***:

  - `<NUL set /p ="this" | openssl dgst ...`
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322238/45375) for more information and the limitations on the limitations on what strings can be output this way; in short: the string mustn't start with `=`, must not contain embedded `"` chars., and must not have leading tabs and/or spaces, which are invariably stripped.
- In **PowerShell, as of v7.1, you currently *cannot* send a string via the pipeline to an external program *without* a trailing newline** - see [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974).

  - The **workaround** is to call `cmd.exe` and use its hack:

    - `cmd /c '<NUL set /p ="this" | openssl dgst ...'`
  - Again, be sure to escape embedded `'` as `''`; if you want to use an *expandable* string (`"..."`) so you can use string interpolation to embed PowerShell variables, escape the embedded `"` as `` `" ``:

    - `` $str = 'this'; cmd /c "<NUL set /p =`"$str`" | openssl dgst ..." ``