# How to create a file with text, date, and file content in command line

Tags: command-line, terminal

I'm looking to create an alais in IOS Terminal that will create a file with a comment at the top of the file and append another file to the end

**Output I would like**

```
\#2Thu Dec  3 14:39:41 MST 2015
--fileContents--
```

**Attempt**

```
echo # > x.txt; date >> x.txt; cat file.txt >>> x.txt;
```

But the results put the `#` and the date on separate lines... How would I do it with keeping them on the same line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)

Comment: @MarcB is that specific to Windows?

Comment: it mentions the unix equivalent in the qusetion itself, and since you haven't mentioned what OS you're on...

Comment: I don't think terminal is available in windows @MarcB

Comment: uh, yes, it is. `cmd.exe`. terminal is a generic term. every os has a terminal of some sort.

Comment: @MarcB that does not give information on how to put contents into a file, nor does it work in "Terminal" the IOS application,

Comment: @MarcB Please advise

Comment: @MarcB which example are you implying answers my inquiry?

Comment: @MarcB please advise

Comment: @MarcB please remove your block unless you can supply direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that adding ` around date inside of an echo executes the statement.

Resolution

```
echo # `date` > x.txt; cat file.txt >> x.txt;
```