# I have a couple of Linux commands, which i want to run on windows machine. How to Run Linux commands from Python on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, batch-file

I have some Linux commands which will generate token. I've automated those commands using OS library form Python on Linux machine. It is working fine.

But, When I try the same code in the windows it is returning nothing.

The following is the code I've tried.

```
uniqueKey = os.popen('echo -n kittu | base64')
data = uniqueKey.read()
print data
```

in Linux I got the following output

```
a210dHU=
```

in windows it is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 Encode "string" - command-line Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046771/base64-encode-string-command-line-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to execute Linux commands on Windows. I have enabled the 'bash' in windows machine. And I have used 'subprocess' library from Python to run 'Linux' commands on Windows. Following is the code.

```
bash = subprocess.Popen(['bash'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result=bash.communicate(input="echo -n kittu|base64")
print result[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Commands are specific to the OS. For example on Linux, `ls` lists files in a directory, while on Windows it's `dir`.

Windows has an `echo` like Linux but does not support the flag `-n`—the two commands are not related, only coinciding in name.

Windows also does not have a `base64` command.

Nor does it use `|` to mean piping, though I believe PowerShell does.

---

Why use OS commands at all? Python supports base64 encoding natively:

```
uniqueKey = base64.b64encode('kittu')
```

Comment: But, is there any other way to automate those Linux commands on Windows using Python. In the first command I have only 'base64'. But the other command has combination of 'openssl','base64'.

Comment: Oh, duh. You're just trying to encode a string to base64. Why use OS commands at all? Python supports it natively. `base64.b64encode(s[, altchars])` - See my edit.

Comment: I tried that. But not working as expected. Manually I'm able to do that from Cygwin. But, I don't find a way to automate it. I've used the following code to automate it. But, it is just  launching the cygwin, not performing any  thing.           p = subprocess.Popen("C:/cygwin64/bin/mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.stdin.write("ls")
    p.stdin.close()
    out = p.stdout.read()
    print (out)

Comment: Ah, but `openssl`. No, there's no easy way to just make things work in Windows, aside from installing Cygwin (a UNIX layer, pretty much like Linux) on Windows and run your Python script from within Cygwin.

Comment: That's probably some other error on your part. I would create a new question with exactly what you tried with Cygwin and ask why you are not seeing an output. Someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use intend to use Linux commands a lot but still want a Windows machine, you can install a Linux subsystem: [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)