# Counter in Batch file for loop - how to keep the number in the same place?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, terminal

I'm writing a batch file in Windows. I need to process a big text file line by line. I'd like to show a counter in the `cmd` window while doing this. The following code works pretty good:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=1

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (myFile.txt) do (
    set /a count+=1
    echo.!count!
)
```

The only problem is that I get a **new line for every count increment**. So the output in the `cmd` window is something like this:

```
---------------------
-   START PROCESS   -
---------------------
1
2
3
4
..
1000
```

What I really want is **a dynamic number displayed** in the terminal window. Something like this:

```
---------------------
-   START PROCESS   -
---------------------
count = 124           <= this number should dynamically increment
```

How do I do that?

**EDIT :**

The post [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line) does explain how to make an echo without starting a new line in the terminal. So this is how I tried to implement it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=1

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (iconOldPathList.txt) do (
    set /a count+=1
    <nul set /p =!count!
)
```

Unfortunately, the result is not a dynamically updating number. What I get is:

```
---------------------
-   START PROCESS   -
---------------------
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
...
```

What I really want is:

```
---------------------
-   START PROCESS   -
---------------------
count = 124           <= this number should dynamically increment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code seems to work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

for /L %%n in (100 -1 1) do (
    <nul set /P "=This window will close in %%n seconds   !CR!"
    ping -n 2 localhost > nul
)
```