# How do i delete an echo/line

Tags: batch-file

How do i delete the output echo in batch? 
When i have something like this

```
    echo test
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul     //using the ping as a pause
    "something to delete the echo"
```

I want to make the executed batch prompt "count down" using the ping as a timed pause.

Comment: Why do you want to hide it after ? You only have to remove `echo test` from your script

Comment: you can echo off to hide the echo line but what exactly you mean, I don't get you clearly. could you explain a little bit more

Comment: You should use a clearer description or better selection of words. For us, _"delete an echo/line"_ imply to delete a line in the Batch file. If you want to "delete the output of a previous echo command in the screen", then this question is a duplicate of [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126279/how-to-clear-selected-lines-in-batch-instead-of-the-whole-screen).

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938489/counter-in-batch-file-for-loop-how-to-keep-the-number-in-the-same-place?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Retrospective deletion is pretty difficult. 
However, if you don't want "echo test" to appear as well as the output, "test" you could replace the line with "@echo test". The @ prefix suppresses output of the command itself.
if you don't want any of the instructuctions to be echoed, just their output, put "@echo off" as the first line of your batch file.