# Dos/Windows batch caret escape in set /P prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping, character, caret

I'm just curious on one specific case of the caret escape in Windows batch:

Please save the following code as a file `ttt.bat`, and run `ttt.bat` on command prompt, why do I have to put 5 repetitions of the caret (or carat?) character `^` to make this ["no new line echo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line) trick work? I only want to put a pipe `'|'` in the echoed string.

There is some documentation on the escaping thing for Windows batch, but for a case study purpose, can you explain what's the meanings of every caret character used in this example? Thanks!

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set foo=Hello world
set bar=Why why

echo|set /P=!foo! ^^^^^| !bar!

EndLocal
```

Comment: Well, if you would write `echo|set /P "=!foo! | !bar!"` then you would not need to escape pipe character at all as being part of a double quoted string. `set /P "variable=prompt text"` respectively `set "variable=string value"` are the preferred methods to assign strings to an environment variable. See [How to set environment variables with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and execute in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and read at least the last paragraph on last output help page.

Comment: I thought the shell  would print the double quotes as well, thank you for pointing out this!

Answer (score 5):

It's obvious :-)

Here are [different phases of the parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115) involved.

The first important phase is here the special character phase, a caret escapes the next characters, important for `^|&<>` characters.

The line will be reduced from

```
echo|set /P=!foo! ^^^^^| !bar!
```

to

```
echo|set /P=!foo! ^^| !bar!
```

As one caret escapes the next, and the last caret escapes the pipe.

The next important phase here is the delayed expansion phase, this phase only occours when at least one `!` is in the line.
In this phase carets escapes also the next character, but here it's only necessary for the caret itself and the `!`, and in this phase the delayed variables are expanded.

From

```
echo|set /P=!foo! ^^| !bar!
```

to

```
echo|set /P=Hello world ^| Why why
```

As you use a pipe here, both sides of the pipe will be transfered to a new cmd.exe process and there the commands will be parsed again.

`cmd.exe /c "echo"` and `cmd /c "set /P=Hello world ^| Why why`

Only `set /P=Hello world ^| Why why` is relavant now.
Again in the special character phase the one caret escapes the pipe character to

```
set /P=Hello world | Why why
```

The delayed expansion phase will not occour, first as delayed expansion is disabled in the new cmd.exe (by default) and second as there aren't any `!` in the line.
That's all!

Btw.
Spawning two processes here is not necessary, a redirection is simpler and faster

```
<nul set /P=!foo! ^^^| !bar!
```

Without delayed expansion, you only need one caret

```
<nul set /P=FOO ^| BAR
```

Or look at the difference of 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

```
echo "carets ^^^"
echo "carets ^^^" !
```

Comment: Did I get it right: durin the delayed expansion parse phase, `^^` is escaped to `^` only in case at least one `!` appears in the parsed command line, so when there is no such character, `^^` remains as is?