# batfile - how to remove the last, empty, line in a file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a csv file produced as:

```
"a","b","c","d"
"a","b","c","d"
```

But on importing it into an application it reads three lines in which I presume is caused by a carriage return character at the end of the 2nd line.  If I open the file in notepad the curosr sits on the 3rd file, hitting back space to return the cursor to the end of line 2 and saving the file works as expected.

How can I remove this carriage return/line feed/return the cursor to the end of line 2?

I'd like to accomplish this in a batfile.  I have tried echoing content and then using type/findstr without success.

Really appreciate it - i've spent a lot of time searching but without success so far.
Thanks

Comment: Related: [Windows batch: echo without new line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433)

Comment: How can I use it to edit the CSV file?  I have tried echoing and using type without any luck.  The csv file is produced by an outside process, my batfile is simply going to copy the file but in doing so also (hopfully) remove this carriage return on the last line.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38527900) below...

Comment: I would argue that there is not an empty line, and your application that is loading the CSV is flawed. CSV are examples of text files, and there is a long standing convention that every line should be terminated by an end-of-line sequence (EOL),  which is carriage return, linefeed on Windows. There are many applications that allow for the last line of a CSV to not end with EOL, But an application should not require that the last line be missing EOL.

Comment: I would definitely agree with the that, may send over a bug report too! I've got it working that's to the answer but it was tedious, I've had to strip down the headers too and I was surprised the destination application couldn't handle that (at least it handled text qualifiers...)

Comment: My rant does not solve your problem. You could use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) `jrepl "\r?\n(?![\s\S])" "" /m /f "yourFile.csv" /o -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `set /P` instead of `echo` as it does not produce a trailing line-break, and add them explictly but for the last line using `echo/`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "FLAG="
> "\path\to\returnfile.csv" (
     for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("\path\to\yourfile.csv") do (
        if defined FLAG echo/
        < nul set /P ="%%L"
        set "FLAG=#"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

See also this post for the `set /P` approach: [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433).

Comment: Hi,Ive just noticed it also removes the leading " from each line, can you explain why?

Comment: I think this can be fixed by a minor change: instead of `set /P "=%%L"` write `set /P ="%%L"` (can't test right now)