# cmd format user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to translate input formatted like this: `abcd12-34defg` and translate it to this: `ab-cd-12-34-de-fg`

My code:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p macid="please enter mac id:" 
echo %macid%
goto start
```

Current output:

```
please enter mac id: abcd12-34defg    
abcd12-34defg
```

Goal:

```
please enter mac id: abcd12-34defg    
ab-cd-12-34-de-fg
```

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php  good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if that's the fixed entry format, this will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p macID="please enter mac id:" 

call :print_token 0 2 -
call :print_token 2 2 -
call :print_token 4 2 -
call :print_token 7 2 -
call :print_token 9 2 -
call :print_token 11 2 

goto :eof

:print_token
echo | set /p dummyVar=!macID:~%1,%2!%3
exit /b 0
```

Regarding the `echo | set /p dummyVar=`, it is used to `echo` values without line breaks. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336754/2316433) for further information.

If you expect a non-fixed input format, then you need to clean up extrange characters first, and then split like shown in this example. After cleaning the input value, you could easily turn the `call :print_token` sequence into a for loop, for improved clarity.

Sample run:

```
please enter mac id:abcd12-34defg
ab-cd-12-34-de-fg
```

Comment: that working fine....
now if i want to use %macID% for further commands ...
how to use the new generated output ?

Comment: @deschus I'm glad it is working correctly. Regarding your new request, you need to open a new question with the specifics of the usage you intend to make. If you found this useful, please remember to upvote and mark as accepted!