# How to print name and version of a tool in cmd in one line?

Tags: cmd, echo, version, packer

I want to print version of e.g. Packer in cmd. This works with `packer --version`. Unfortunately this prints the version number only - but not the name of the tool. This is the case with some other tools (e.g. VirtualBox, etc.), too.

`C:\_TEMP
λ packer --version
0.10.1
λ vboxmanage --version
5.1.4r110228`

So my idea was to do somethink like `echo Packer & packer --version` but this prints in two lines:

`C:\_TEMP
λ echo Packer & packer --version
Packer
0.10.1`

Now, how can I print Name + version number in one line? So that the result looks like:

`Packer 0.10.1
 Virtualbox 5.1.4r110228`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result of version to an environment variable

```
for /f %a in ('packer --version') do set VERSION=%a
```

then echo what you like

```
echo packer %VERSION%
```

Explanation:

- You're looping over the output of `packer --version` (there's only 1 line though so VERSION gets set only one)
- if you need only one token from the line then you can specify eg "tokens=2"  for the second space delimited token.

**NOTE:** These commands work from the command line. To use in a batch file turn %a into %%a.

Comment: Damn, that's so much work for such a little thing to achieve :))) but I guess there is no easier way(?). Thank you for additional explanation and the NOTE, it's very good - I am sure I would have run into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also (ab)use `set /p` for that (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433/2152082)):

```
<nul set /p "=Packer: "
packer --version
<nul set /p "=VirtualBox: "
vboxmanage --version
```