# automatic EOL conversion snippet?

Tags: eol

I am working on a batch script that produces the deployment shell script according to my input, and I found my generated shell script has EOL `\r\n`, so I need to add a procedure to convert this file to use `\n`. I was looking for a solution in native batch but failed, so now I am trying to do it in other approaches.

The input is a typical shell script of commands with `\r\n` as EOL.

The output should be the same shell script with `\n` as EOL.

Any method that can be done in Windows environment will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anything like DOS2Unix for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368781/anything-like-dos2unix-for-windows)

Comment: DOS2Unix seems to be a good answer of it but I would not consider it duplicated, as I am also looking for the solution that can have least extra dependency added to the script. That is, I am trying to use everything available in my environment to achieve the target, and I believe the way to achieve is not unique.

Comment: So something like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803502/echo-text-with-unix-line-endings-from-a-windows-batch-bat-script

Answer (score 0):

nodejs approach:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('apply_patchx.sh','utf8',(err,data)=>{
    fs.writeFile('apply_patch.sh',data.replace(/\r?\n/g,"\n"),()=>{
        console.log('converted');
    });
});
```

Call by `node rn2n.js`, input embedded in script.

Java approach:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class RN2N {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("apply_patchx.sh"));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("apply_patch.sh"));
            for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;){
                bw.write(line.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\\n", "\\\\n"));
            }
            br.close();
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("converted");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Call by `java RN2N`, input embedded in script.