# Batch - Multiple linear variables in one ECHO

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I make multiple "linear" variables on one line?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
...more stuff

set /p input=(Number):
...more
:somewhere
(some commands to set variables)
:loop
if %loopcounter%==%input% goto somewhere
set /a loopcounter=loopcounter+1
set display=!d%loopcounter%!
echo %display%
pause
goto loop

So I get:
var1
var2
var3
var(anything up to %number%)
But how do I make it:
var1 var2 var3 var(anything up to %number%)
```

echo %var1% %var2% %var3% might not work because the amount of variables can go up to anything

Is there a way to "add" new variables to a variable without resetting it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<nul set/p ="%display% "` (<-- space after) for that.

After a totally correct request by @jeb I will add some explanation:

With `<` you can send data over the standard input. In this case this substitutes the usual typing and pressing enter of the user that would usually type here due to the `/p` switch.
Sending `nul` results in an empty input.
So the only thing displayed is the string displayed asking for the user input (usually) which in this case is your variable.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line#comment8520146_7105690)

Comment: Using quotes makes the trailing space visible: `< nul set /P ="%display% "`

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the hint. Have to work on the finer things a bit more I guess :)

Comment: You should add some explanations, what the code does. As for the normal user it's not obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You could concat the strings first in a new variable.

```
set "display="
for /L %%n in (1 1 %input%) do (
  set "display=!display! !var%%n!"
)
echo !display!
```

Comment: Awesome! EXACTLY what I needed. I just need to reverse the variables now

Comment: @HuskyHus If this is "EXACTLY" what you needed be fair and mark this as accepted answer. (Although I assume that it is already to late and this Husky is long gone...)