# unable to write in line variable writing in batch cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I apologize for the vagueness of my question.

I wanted to be able to take information and stack it in a file, the pull the information from the file in line.

The way that I am able to do this at this time is with:

```
:: simple setting of variables
Set var1=var..
Set var2=var..
Set var3=var..
Set fullvar=%var1%%var2%%var3%
:: now push to file
Echo fullvar > file
```

Before I asked my question I did not realize I could stack my variables in this way.

I am going back through batch tutorials.

Can this question be closed?

Thank you for you assistance.

### Original transcript below

I am looking for a way to put my variables into a file in line.
With >> I can append a new line, I want to have my var% in line...

Ex:

```
Type file2
```

returns
    %var1% %var2% %var3%

Instead of;

```
%var1%
%var2%
%var3%

:eof
```

I want to be able to use them as %1 %2 %3 in my batch program.

Here is the basic information I am using.

```
Echo off
cls
ping /n 1 ipaddress1Var > file
ping /n 1 ipaddress2Var >> file
findstr /i "ttl=" file > file2
Type file2
pause
:eof
```

this returns the line included with ttl= to the new file. 
I am not sure how to write what I want this to do;

When I > or >> to file2 I want to add to the line that it is written to instead of a new line.

Unfortunatly I do not have my computer I wrote the batch file on with me. I want to expand the capabilities of the script.

I am learning more intermediate batch programming on a WinXP laptop.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would help. This does not google well.

Cheers

Maybe

```
Echo %var1% %var2% %var3% > file#
```

Would work for building the file in line. I am just not sure how to read and re-assign the variables properly....

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Well for starters you are not referencing your environmental variables correctly. Regardless of that I am not understanding your explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line). I _think_ this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Its similar but not in echo. I suppose i could use echo -n to >> into my file..

Comment: You would `set /p "=%var1%" <nul >>file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

**MyFile.bat**

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('ping /n 1 cnn.com    ^| findstr TTL') do (set TTL_1=%%a)
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('ping /n 1 google.com ^| findstr TTL') do (set TTL_2=%%a)
echo %TTL_1% %TTL_2% > OUTPUT.txt
```

After this, the file `OUTPUT.txt` contains:

```
Reply from 151.101.128.73: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=56 Reply from 216.58.194.142: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54
```

(two entries, back-to-back, on one line)