# How to convert a List in text file to single line with commas

Tags: batch-file

I have text file with data as a list with each word on new line:

> ```
> 'GBL26707819i'
> 'GBL26707944i'
> 'GBL26707972i'
> 'GBL26708071i'
> 'GBL26708070i'
> ```

I want to show it in single line seperated by commas.
For example, the ticket numbers are `'GBL26707819i','GBL26707944i','GBL26707972i'` etc.

Comment: I want a batch script for the above

Comment: This is not a free code writing service! You have to share your efforts and describe what you have trouble with. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: Related: [Windows batch: echo without new line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433)

Answer (score 1):

Using powershell:

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines("file.txt")  
$result = [string]::Join(",", $content)
write $result
```