# How to remove the new line being printed in the .dat file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am doing an ftp batch script. It's an mget command but I have an error with the file name because it has ":"(colon)s in it. So my codes does a for loop which does the `get` command multiple times. My problem is, is that the .dat file has an empty line which is an error for the ftp command.

Below is my code:

```
@echo off& setlocal enableextensions

Echo open sample.net>second.dat
Echo user»second.dat
Echo pass»second.dat
Echo ascii»second.dat
Echo cd path/path/path»second.dat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file_list.txt) do (
set "remote=%%a"
echo get !remote:~0,-1! !remote::=.!»second.dat)
endlocal
Echo bye»second.dat
ftp -v -i -s:second.dat
del second.dat
pause
```

The `file_list.txt` is the list of file names that I need to rename using this code

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (file_list.txt) do (
    set "remote=%%a"
    echo get !remote:~0,-1! !remote::=.!»second.dat)
    endlocal
```

The output file is this one

```
sample.net
user
pass
ascii
cd path/path/path
get logsample-txt-871749063-10-17-2017_22:00:05:692474.txt logsample-txt-871749063-10-17-2017_22.00.05.692474.txt

get logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08:00:57:671751.txt logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08.00.57.671751.txt

get logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08:00:07:724779.txt logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08.00.07.724779.txt

bye
```

What I what is, I need to remove the blank spaces for the ftp command to read it properly

```
sample.net
user
pass
ascii
cd path/path/path
get logsample-txt-871749063-10-17-2017_22:00:05:692474.txt logsample-txt-871749063-10-17-2017_22.00.05.692474.txt
get logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08:00:57:671751.txt logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08.00.57.671751.txt
get logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08:00:07:724779.txt logsample-txt-871749063-10-18-2017_08.00.07.724779.txt
bye
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)

Comment: Specifically, check out Jeb's comment for the accepted answer.

Comment: His answer makes my lines into a single line, what I'm trying to do is just remove the empty lines. @SomethingDark

Comment: If an `echo` gives two newlines, then `<nul set /p=` will give one newline, not zero. Without a hexdump of file_list.txt, I can't say for certain why you're getting the blank lines (my current guess is that you somehow have an extra newline character on each line for some reason). `for /f "delims=" %%A in (second.dat) do echo %%A >>third.dat` will get rid of the blank lines, though.

Comment: Also, I've never seen FTP care about blank lines, which makes me wonder how you're using the dat file in the first place.

Comment: When it has spaces in the .dat file the ftp reads it as "No such file or directory" but when I remove it, it completely downloads the file as is. @SomethingDark

Comment: And you're just running `ftp -s second.dat`?

Comment: "ftp -s:second.dat" if you mean this, yes. @SomethingDark

Comment: Weird. Whatever, just run the `for` loop I suggested; `for` loops automatically skip over blank lines.

Comment: it does not remove it. I tried it.

Comment: I am unable to replicate your results. Please upload file_list.txt to some file hosting site so I can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @SomethingDark https://www.mediafire.com/file/3ov0phc1ifwuqde/file_list.txt

Comment: Oh God, the file is using \r as the newline character instead of \n or \r\n. That explains a lot. Give me a bit; this isn't even a little bit normal but there's almost certainly an easy way to convert newlines to something reasonable.

Comment: @SomethingDark I get the list using this command in ftp `mls - nameoffile.txt`

Comment: According to https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks, try getting the file with binary mode instead of ascii mode.

Comment: I was able to fix it, because of the comment that you posted. Instead of using this command `mls - nameoffile.txt` which uses the spacing that you said. I used this instead `Echo ls -h file_list.txt>>first.dat` Thanks for the help! @SomethingDark