# Cursor blink in front of text

Tags: batch-file, echo

I want the cursor to be infront of the text like this:

```
              Hello_
```

Not

```
              Hello
_
```

But I don't know how to do this. Can you help?

This is a batch file and has @echo off

"I used spacing to align it to the middle"

Comment: the cursor is after "Hello" and not before "echo"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)

Comment: Invalid. It doesn't save my spacing. I used to align it to the middle I put the spaces inside the quotes

Comment: You should put previous requirement (_"I used to align it to the middle"_) in the question and in the example. In the example the cursor is _below_ the "H" of "Hello", that is, with no spacing...

Comment: Oof got question banned. "I made it more clear now"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
set /P "=.%BS%         Hello" < nul
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21283496)

Comment: @Lee: Why you deleted this answer? I am afraid you are confused.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: The OP wanted that "the cursor to be in front of" the "Hello" word like this: `Hello_` (where the underscore represents the cursor)...

Comment: @OwenPauling: ... and later added that "I used to align it to the middle I put the spaces inside the quotes".

Comment: @Rob: My solution achieve _exactly that_! (Did you tested it?)  **`:(`**