# Batch file: Combine echos into one line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to dump all the file names in a folder without extension into a text file. They should be in one line separated by commas.

So in my folder I have

- File1.bin
- File2.bin
- ....

---

With

```
(for %%a in (.\*.bin) do @echo %%~na,) >Dump.txt
```

I got

```
File1,
File2,
```

But what I want in the end is a text file with, so one long combined string.

```
File1,File2,...
```

I'm kinda stuck here and probably need something else than echo.
Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: So why not assign them to a variable in the FOR command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (.\*.txt) do (
    <nul set /p=%%~nxa,
)
```

check also the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line) and the dbenham's one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also pointing out the other one, might be useful for the next problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could also leverage [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) for this task:

```bat
@"%__APPDIR__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "( Get-Item -Path '.\*' -Filter '*.bin' | Where-Object { -Not $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName ) -Join ',' | Out-File -FilePath '.\dump.txt'"
```

This could probably be shortened, *if necessary*, to:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GI .\*.bin|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select -Exp BaseName) -Join ','>.\dump.txt"
```