# Batch Echo Style: two statements into same line

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have some code running, I wanne make it nicer though.

Currently my code is:

```
@echo off
echo Starting Program 1 ... >> %log%
call Program1.cmd
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    echo Error. >> %log%
) else (
    echo Success. >> %log%
)
```

I would like to keep the two echos within the code because I find it better for debug reasons. However, I do not like two output lines for it. How do I need to change the code to get this output:

> Starting Program 1 ... Success

Thank you for your help,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the first message into a variable and then use it in the last redirection to file.

To use your code it would look like this:

```
@echo off
set "log=C:\t\so\batch\log.log"
set "message=Starting Program 1 ... "
call Program1.cmd
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    echo %message% Error. >> %log%
) else (
    echo %message% Success. >> %log%
)
```

**Edit** In my script above you may lose the logging information if something goes seriously wrong with the called script.

You could do it like this:

```
@echo off
set "log=C:\t\so\batch\log.log"
echo | set /p message="Starting Program 1 ... " >> %log%
call Program1.cmd
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    echo Error. >> %log%
) else (
    echo Success. >> %log%
)
```

The `/p` switch:

> The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of
>   input entered by the user.  Displays the specified promptString before
>   reading the line of input.  The promptString can be empty.

**Note:** here the message is just a dummy variable.

There is a complex answer from [dbehham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468559/6059896) on this topic.

Comment: do I risk losing "Starting Program 1 ..." in log if there is an error during call program1.cmd ?
Can one just remove the last linebreak within the log file?

Comment: @PeterFrey Yes you do lose that information if you directly the call script hangs or such unexptected issue occurs, otherwise, you should get the result based on the `%ERRORLEVEL%`.  Removing the line break is unncessarly complex.  I'll post some ways how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can misuse the `set /p` command to output a line without line feed.

```
@echo off
<nul set /p "=Starting Program 1 ..." >> %log%
call Program1.cmd
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    echo Error. >> %log%
) else (
    echo Success. >> %log%
)
```