# How to get output of a PowerShell command and of command ECHO in Windows batch file output on one line?

Tags: powershell, datetime, batch-file, cmd, echo

The following command line does not work in a Windows batch file:

```
Powershell.exe -Command Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' echo "Hello World"
```

The expected result is: **2021-05-09 12:00:00 Hello World**

But PowerShell outputs the error message:

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "echo" to type "System.DateTime".
Error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0."
At line:1 char:9
+ Get-Date <<<<  -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' echo Hello World
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

How to get output of the PowerShell command to get date and time in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and of the command **ECHO** in Windows batch file output on one line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch Echo Style: two statements into same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729213/batch-echo-style-two-statements-into-same-line)

Comment: No. It doesn't. In this command, I have called Powershell command in cmd. But at the same time, I need to use ECHO command as well. And the question is how to combine two command into one line? I have no idea add what syntax or parameter to implement on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command line to use in a Windows batch file is:

```
@for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`) do @echo %%I Hello World
```

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file starts one more `cmd.exe` in background with option `/c` and the command line specified within set of command **FOR** as additional arguments. The second `cmd.exe` instance runs `powershell.exe` to get local date time and outputs it in the specified format. This output of PowerShell written to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of background command process is captured by the command process which is processing the batch file and is processed after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself by the cmd internal command **FOR**.

The output line is assigned as is to the loop variable `I` because of using `delims=` to define an empty list of string delimiters and the fact that the line does not start with a semicolon which is the default end of line character. The string value assigned to loop variable `I` is output with the text by the command **ECHO** to handle **STDOUT** of the command process which is processing the batch file.

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `for /?` and read the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page.

See also the answers on:

- [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124351/)
- [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/)

Answer (score 3):

You could of course just do it like this:

```sh
PowerShell Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Hello World
```

Although, as this is from a pre-written batch-file, I'd advise that you use full paths and more readable and understandable syntax:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command "Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Hello World"
```

Comment: It seems to me that your answer fits more the question as OP doesn't ask to retrieve the date in an env variable but to display the date alongside the output of a batch echo command. Why not using then the 'escaping' way like `Powershell.exe -Command Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' ^| Write-Host -NoNewline & echo  "Hello World"` ?

Comment: TBF, there are many ways of achieving it @Zilog80, but for me, that is less basic, especially for the OP's example, and I didn't want this to be an answer about how to use PowerShell.