# How to change color in python (windows)

Tags: python

Original: `os.system("echo \u001b[31mU have Been Hacked").`

And I have tried `print(u"")`, `print()` but nothing works and I don't want to install any libraries so can someone help me?

Comment: This comment is not clear at all. Try explaining your problem in depth

Answer (score 0):

Use [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) library.

```
import colorama

# Init allows color printing on windows terminals
# and autoreset resets to default color after each print
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

print(colorama.Fore.Green + "Hello world!")
```

Comment: *i dont want to install any libaries*...

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to print colors on windows terminals without the colorama library. Unless you are strictly targeting [windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Answer (score 0):

So this is without installing any libraries
my implementation is

```
import os


def printWhiteOnRed(s):
    os.system("echo |set /p out=\u001b[97;101m")
    print(s)
    os.system("echo |set /p out=\u001b[0m")

s= "you have done well"
printWhiteOnRed(s)
```

`|set /p out=`
This is to supress line ending in the command prompt, see this Stack Overflow answer.

`\u001b`
This is the ANSI escape character

`[97;101m`
This are the colours for white foreground on red background.

`[0m`
This is the reset code to ensure any further output is in normal style

Sources:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line/11336754#11336754)
[github](https://gist.github.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011#file-win10colors-cmd)