# Windows batch: how to execute a command so that its not followed by a newline

Tags: windows, batch-file

Consider this:

```
cd ..
```

The output of the above command is:

```
C:\Users\rodio>cd ..
                         <--- Get rid of this empty line.
C:\Users>
```

What I want to achieve, however, is:

```
C:\Users\rodio>cd ..
C:\Users>
```

Is it possible in a batch file (`.bat`, `.cmd`)?

Comment: No. The empty line is produced by _the executed command_. Try: `set /P "=Hello" < NUL`

Comment: More specifically, the command output (usually) ends with a `CRLF`. Then the Prompt starts with another `CRLF` (to be sure it's on a new line in case the previous command/script does *not*  end with a `CRLF` (like @Aacini's code line) (A. check the output of a simple script with `echo on` vs. `echo off`. You can see, that the prompt adds an additional linefeed) (B. enter `echo off` at the command line and retry your commands. You see that the additional linefeed is missing now - together with the prompt)

Comment: What is your real goal? Perhaps, you want to write a batch file, the output there could be optimized the way you're asking for

Comment: @jeb Yes, it will go to a batch file.

Comment: Then you should show some real examples from your batch code, as `cd ..` doesn't ouput anything. Probably this solves your not asked question [echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line/7105690#7105690)

Comment: @jeb I already have seen the post you linked. Close. All I need is the same for the `cd` command.

Comment: As said, the `cd <path>` has no output at all, so there is no linefeed that could be removed. But without showing your real problem (you only showed unrelated code) it's hard to solve

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is an X-Y problem, and the need to remove the newline is caused by *your* solution to an unstated requirement?  The behaviour is  with cmd.exe rather than the `cd` command specifically.

In a batch file you can block *all* command echo and prompt output with `@echo off`.  So for example:

```
@echo off
echo Start
cd ..
echo End
```

Outputs:

```
Start
End
```

If you need to report the current working directory, then that is output by `cd` with no parameter: e.g:

```
@echo off
echo Start
cd ..
cd
echo End
```

executed starting from `C:\Users\<username>` outputs:

```
Start
C:\Users
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Only guessing your real question...

```
@echo off
echo The current path is %CD% and here is no line feed
```

or for other commands without a shadow variable

```
@echo off
REM *** Get the output of a command
FOR /F "tokens=* %%A in ('ver') do set "verion=%%A"
echo The verion "%version%" was found
```