# cmd.exe echo ===> or <=== without newline and with one or more space character before and after in pure batch, as a one-liner solution

Tags: batch-file

Output result should be:

```
Text(Nr1,line1) ===>  Text(Nr2,line1)  ===> Text(Nr3,line1)  ===> ... ===>  Text(Nr"n",line1)
Text(Nr1,line2) <===  Text(Nr2,line2)  <=== Text(Nr3,line2)  <=== ... <===  Text(Nr"m",line2)
Text(Nr1,line3) <===  Text(Nr2,line3)  ===> Text(Nr3,line3)  <=== ... ===>  Text(Nr"o",line3)
Text(Nr1,line4) <===> Text(Nr2,line4) <===> Text(Nr3,line4) <===> ... <===> Text(Nr"p",line4)
Text(Nr1,line5)  ---> Text(Nr2,line5) <---> Text(Nr3,line5) <--- ... --->   Text(Nr"q",line5)
:                :    :               :     :               :        :      :
```

`echo | set /p====>` and
`echo | set /p=<===` result `SYNTAX ERROR`

`nircmdc.exe consolewrite ===>` shows as requested `===>`, but followed with newline which does not allow the same line to continue in the Windows cmd console.

**[Edit /]**

`<nul set /p "====>"` when run in an elevated Windows 10 Command Prompt, results in a syntax error message:

```
G:\><nul set /p "====>"
Syntaxfehler
```

Comment: I would prefer to see all of the code you have written to output the five lines you have shown as your expectation, rather than just a partial command with no context. We really do need to see something more specific in order to be able to assist you with your task.

Comment: Considering no batch command results in the string "SYNTAX ERROR" I'd be curious to see the context of those commands. That said, try `<nul set /p "====>"` instead of `echo | set /p====>` and see if that works.

Comment: As already asked, please show us where and how you are getting the text strings you are trying to separate with these arrow like separators. Context is important, and I'm now not the only person to have asked.

Comment: to get around the syntax error, you need to escape with the ^. But set/p doesn't allow the equal sign as first character. Have a look at the high rated comment to the marked answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line