# Python HMAC Digest differs from OpenSSL command

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, sha256, hmac

I need to create a signature from a private key and a message in Python using HMAC SHA256.

The OpenSSL command, ran in the command window, is the following:

```
echo -n "recvWindow=0&symbol=BTC-USDT&timestamp=1696751141337" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "mheO6dR8ovSsxZQCOYEFCtelpuxcWGTfHw7te326y6jOwq5WpvFQ9JNljoTwBXZGv5It07m9RXSPpDQEK2w" -hex
SHA2-256(stdin)= 04003ddfe0e52231a2bdfe94e8d3f5a369522b82f28b7d5511414b4d7f87d698
```

The Python code used to recreate the same behavior is the following:

```
def calcu(key, data):
    hmac_digest = hmac.new(key.encode("UTF-8"),
                           data.encode("UTF-8"),
                           hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return hmac_digest

key = "mheO6dR8ovSsxZQCOYEFCtelpuxcWGTfHw7te326y6jOwq5WpvFQ9JNljoTwBXZGv5It07m9RXSPpDQEK2w"
data = "recvWindow=0&symbol=BTC-USDT&timestamp=1696751141337"

sign = calcu(key, data)

print(sign.upper())
```

yielding: F8D883609DFD31C824FEB4DE865B071008DEDB1D461451FA70847875C8E7A7A2

What tells me that there is some basic mistake that I am making is that if I use a simple string, like 333 for key and data, the results keep differing from the OpenSSL and Python implementation:

Example:

OpenSSL CMD

```
echo -n "333" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "333" -hex
SHA2-256(stdin)= 32fc726256e8a10d99fbef0d7b27fa51e932ea6cd76530fcfb4641057a813bd8
```

Python

```
def calcu(key, data):
    hmac_digest = hmac.new(key.encode("UTF-8"),
                           data.encode("UTF-8"),
                           hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return hmac_digest

key = "333"
data = "333"

sign = calcu(key, data)

print(sign.upper())
```

0006A5A7658EBA166B26B598748E821E943B769C97A6F366C723712E6CD92DEB
I also tried with b"" and r"" strings, no success with that neither.

What am I overlooking? I tried different encoding like UTF-8, 16, 32, ascii, and so on but none made this work

edit1: I am running Windows 10, OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024), Python 3.10, pyopenssl 24.0.0.

The problem was that Windows was not taking the -n as a parameter, but as part of the input. So, as Topaco and Tim Peters said, using /p= {...} solved it for me.

Comment: Check your outputs against the examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC#Examples

Your Python code reproduces the SHA-258 sample output. Don't know about your `dgst` output.

Comment: When I run

`
echo -n "recvWindow=0&symbol=BTC-USDT&timestamp=1696751141337" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "mheO6dR8ovSsxZQCOYEFCtelpuxcWGTfHw7te326y6jOwq5WpvFQ9JNljoTwBXZGv5It07m9RXSPpDQEK2w" -hex 
` I get ``f8d883609dfd31c824feb4de865b071008dedb1d461451fa70847875c8e7a7a2`, which is exactly the same thing that Python returns.  You're sure you copied the strings perfectly?

Comment: Likewise, when I type your `echo -n "333" ....` command, I get a completely different output. Exactly what the Python outputs.  Is there something strange about your openssl??

Comment: Probably depends on the OS and/or OpenSSL version, which is why both should be posted. I can reproduce the result of the OP on Windows (10) when the OpenSSL statement is entered in the console. Everything following the first blank after the echo until immediately before the pipe is interpreted as input and a linebreak is added at the end. This can be verified if in the Python program `data = "-n \"333\" \r\n"` is used and the same output is generated, see https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/WSQ (and https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/WSR for the longer input).

Comment: On Windows, the line break can be suppressed as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7105690/9014097), e.g. `echo|set /p="333"|openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "333" -hex` works for me, i.e. returns `0006a5a7658eba166b26b598748e821e943b769c97a6f366c723712e6cd92deb`.

Comment: If the OP is running on Windows,, there's a deeper problem: the Windows "echo" not only doesn't support an `-n` argument, it doesn't complain about one either. `echo -n "xyz"` actually produces `b'-n "xyz" \r\n'` Although that may vary some depending on which shell they're using (I used cmd.exe).