# Clearing the windows Environment variable: %ERRORLEVEL%

Tags: cmd

After running a MS DOS command in cmd.exe i was checking the exit code using echo %ERRORLEVEL%. However I guess before running this i should clear the variable: %ERRORLEVEL%.

Am i correct? Also how to clear this variable?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to reset ERRORLEVEL to zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113727/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-reset-errorlevel-to-zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`verify`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754978%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command.  We are causing the ErrorLevel variable to be reset by just performing a command that we know will succeed.  So this can be done with any command that you know will succeed.  Verify is just the default from what I have seen.

```
verify >nul
```

Also, you will want to only clear the variable before calling the command that returns the exit code.

```
verify >nul
command that returns an exit code
echo %ErrorLevel%
```

Comment: There's no need to clear `%ERRORLEVEL%` before running a command that returns an exit code, because the former content will automatically be replaced with the new exit code.

Answer (score 4):

As twasbrillig wrote, I think this is already answered in:

[What is the easiest way to reset ERRORLEVEL to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113727/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-reset-errorlevel-to-zero?lq=1)

And I would mark as best the answer:

```
cmd /c exit /b 0
```