# If Notepad.exe is running then taskkill if not running go to next statement

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, taskkill

I need help writing batch code.

In the initial state of my batch script I need to check if `notepad.exe` is running
if it is running then 
 `taskkill /im notepad.exe` elsif `notepad.exe` is not running then go to next batch statement/code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply execute `taskkill /im notepad.exe` in all cases. If it's not running, then `taskill` will having nothing to kill and will just return.

In that situation, `taskkill` will report an error and set the error level. You can suppress the reporting of the error by redirecting standard error:

```
taskkill /im notepad.exe 2> nul
```

As for the error level, you can just ignore that and it will be cleared by the next command that you execute. Or if needed, you can [clear it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113727/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-reset-errorlevel-to-zero).

This approach is, in my view, better than trying to anticipate whether or not `taskkill` will succeed. You won't be able to anticipate all possible failure modes and since `taskkill` itself performs the very check that you are asking about, I think you may as well leave that check to `taskkill`.

Comment: Possibly the asker was looking for **taskkill /im notepad.exe || exit /b**

Comment: won't it throw error? if it does it may not execute next statements?

Comment: It reports an error. And I show how to suppress that. But it will carry on executing the next statement. Remember this is batch we are talking about, not a real programming language!  ;-)

Comment: @joojaa Judging by the comments, it looks like that is not the case

Comment: Thanks lol I you got me confused when you said real programming language.

Comment: On Windows 10, Adding `2> nul` to the `taskkill` command creates a "nul" file I'm unable to delete, only by `rm nul`. Any way to bypass this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try `taskkill /fi "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe"`
Not finding notepad.exe will only throw an info instead of an error.

Comment: +1 That's quite nice. Avoids needing to reset error level. However, your final statement is misleading. Errors don't stop execution. Execution just plugs on in the face of errors.