# Why can't get exit code of batch file executed with command start?

Tags: batch-file

When I run command `Start C:\temp\sub2.bat` in a command prompt window, errorlevel set is `4` and this is correct because a file which is indicated in batch does not exist. But when I run through this below, errorlevel returns `0`. I have no idea why the exit codes are different.

Can anyone give me an advice for the reason?

```
@echo off
Call :Sub1
GOTO :EOF

:Sub1
start C:\temp\sub2.bat
echo %errorLevel%
```

Comment: The `start` command finished successfully, the `%errorlevel%` reflects that.

Comment: Since `start` does not wait until the batch file `sub2.bat` has finished executing, you cannot get its `ErrorLevel` in the calling batch file (you'd need to add the switch `/WAIT`); you better run `sub2.bat` using [`call`](http:ss64.com/nt/call.html), then you get what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Read the answer on [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) It explains the 4 methods which exist to run a batch file from within a batch file and what are the differences.

You use command `start` which results in starting a new command process running parallel to the command process already executing your batch file for execution of `C:\temp\sub2.bat`.

The current command process immediately continues the execution of posted batch file and evaluates the exit code of command `start` which is 0 on successfully starting the executable or batch file.

You should use the command `call` to run the batch file as subroutine in your batch file and which makes it possible to evaluate the exit code set by `C:\temp\sub2.bat`.

```
@echo off
call C:\temp\sub2.bat
if errorlevel 1 echo There was an error with exit code %ERRORLEVEL%.
```

It would be also possible to start the other batch file in a new command process and what on its termination for example with `exit 4` in current batch file.

```
@echo off
start /wait C:\temp\sub2.bat
if errorlevel 1 echo There was an error with exit code %ERRORLEVEL%.
```

In general it is not advisable to use `exit` without option `/B` as this results always in exiting the command process independent on calling hierarchy which makes it also impossible to debug a batch file by running it from within a command prompt window.

In case of `C:\temp\sub2.bat` really contains `exit ExitCode` without option `/B` and for some unknown reason the batch file can't be edited, it is really necessary to start `C:\temp\sub2.bat` in a separate command process and wait for its termination with `start /wait`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `if /?`
- `start /?`

Read also the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

See also the Stack Overflow questions:

- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)