# 'rename' command sets ERRORLEVEL to 0, even on failure

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In my batch file, I wonder why I can't create a hook for error handling if `rename` fails. I create a folder `foo` and have a shell changing its cwd to foo so that the folder should not be renamable. Then I start my script:

```
for %%x in (%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%") do (
    for %%y in (foo) do (
        if exist "%%~x\%%~y" (
            rename "%%~x\%%~y" _to_be_removed
            echo %ERRORLEVEL%
            IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo We got a problem.)
        )
    )
)
```

Unfortunately, I get the notification that the folder cannot be deleted because it is in use:

```
Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.
0
```

Huh? `rename` failed, but `%ERRORLEVEL%` is zero? This should not be possible, no?

Comment: To get a _new_ value that change inside a `(code block)`, you need to use this form: `!errorlevel!` and include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning; search for "Delayed Expansion" in this forum... I also suggest you to review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886)

Comment: @Aacini : great, that's it. If you'd make your hint an answer, I could accept it!

Comment: If you open up a cmd prompt and read the help for the `IF` command you can also use this style of error checking. `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO We got a PROBLEM.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a *new* value that change inside a `(code block)`, you need to use this form: `!errorlevel!` and include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning; search for "Delayed Expansion" in this forum...

Answer (score 1):

The help output on running in a command prompt window `if /?` explains how to test for exit code of previous command/script/application outside a command block as well as inside a command block working from MS-DOS to currently latest Windows 11.

The solution is simply using:

```
if errorlevel 1 echo We got a problem.
```

instead of the lines

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo We got a problem.)
```

It is really so easy to test if a previously executed command exited with a value **greater or equal** `1` indicating an error on execution instead of `0` indicating a successful execution.

It is also possible testing on a specific exit code value for [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) like **ROBOCOPY** or programs like *RAR* or *7-Zip* by using:

```
if errorlevel 5 if not errorlevel 6 echo Exit code is 5.
```

The first condition `if errorlevel 5` checks if the exit code is **greater or equal** `5` which means it cannot be less than `5` on this condition evaluates to true.

The second condition `if not errorlevel 6` checks if the exit code is **NOT greater or equal** `6` which evaluates to true only on exit code is **less than** `6`.

The exit code value **greater or equal** `5` **AND less than** `6` must be `5` to fulfill both conditions.

I recommend to see also the Stack Overflow pages:

- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/)
- [Difference between Dynamic Environment Variables and Normal Environment Variables in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207037/)