# How to ensure every command is Successful in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file with 10 lines and 5 functions in a batch script. How can I ensure that all the commands in a batch file are successful.

In other way, what's the logic to calculate return  code of each command at the end of a script.

```
1. @ECHO OFF

 2. if not exist "%Destination%\%NAME%" md %Destination%\%NAME%

 3. if not exist "%Destination%\%NAME2%" md %Destination%\%NAME2%

 4. rmdir %Destination%\%NAME3%
 5. if not exist "%Destination%\NAME4%" md %Destination%\%NAME4%
 6. cd /d X:\test1
```

in the above 5 lines, 4th line returns %ERRORLEVEL% 1 and 6th line returns the same. But, I could not put IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 after every command. So, how could i script to handle this.

Comment: show an example

Comment: Instead of checking the existence use `md %Destination%\%NAME% 2>Nul` to suppress errors. Otherwise use [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) with `||` on fail and `&&` on success.

Comment: In Line 4 the path is not double quoted, in case of spaces in `%Destination%` this might fail.

Comment: I want those lines to be failed. But, I want return code of each line and function at the end of a script.

Comment: If you _want_ the error level to be 1 for lines 4 and 6, why not use `if %errorlevel%==1` for those two lines and `if %errorlevel%==0` for the other lines?

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly save your file as `.cmd` instead of `.bat` for better error handling. Also always enclose your paths with double quotes. Then I suggest you test existance as well to overcome errorlevel.

```
If exist "%Destination%\%NAME3%" rmdir "%Destination%\%NAME3%"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code example I suggest following:

```
@echo off
rem Verify the existence of all used environment variables.
for %%I in (Destination NAME NAME2 NAME3 NAME4) do (
    if not defined %%I (
        echo Error detected by %~f0:
        echo/
        echo Environment variable name %%I is not defined.
        echo/
        exit /B 4
    )
)

rem Verify the existence of all used directories by creating them
rem independent on existing already or not and next verifying if
rem the directory really exists finally.
for %%I in ("%Destination%\%NAME%" "%Destination%\%NAME2%") do (
    md %%I 2>nul
    if not exist "%%~I\" (
        echo Error detected by %~f0:
        echo/
        echo Directory %%I
        echo does not exist and could not be created.
        echo/
        exit /B 3
     )
)

rem Remove directories independent on their existence and verify
rem if the directories really do not exist anymore finally.
for %%I in ("%Destination%\%NAME3%") do (
    rd /Q /S %%I 2>nul
    if exist "%%~I\" (
        echo Error detected by %~f0:
        echo/
        echo Directory %%I
        echo still exists and could not be removed.
        echo/
        exit /B 2
     )
)

cd /D X:\test1 2>nul
if /I not "%CD%" == "X:\test1" (
    echo Error detected by %~f0:
    echo/
    echo Failed to set "X:\test1" as current directory.
    echo/
    exit /B 1
)
```

This batch file handles nearly all possible errors which could occur during execution of this batch file. A remaining problem could be caused by an environment variable containing one or more double quotes in its value. The solution would be using delayed expansion.

Linux shell script interpreters have the option `-e` to exit immediately execution of a script if any command or application returns with a value not equal `0`. But Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` does not have such an option. The options of `cmd.exe` can be read on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`.

So it is necessary to use in a batch file:

- `if exist "..." exit /B 1` or `goto :EOF`
- `if not exist "..." exit /B 1` or `goto :EOF`
- `if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1` or `goto :EOF`
- ... `|| exit /B 1` or `... || goto :EOF`

See also the Stack Overflow articles:

- [Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/)
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/)
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)