# How to run a java process in the background and exit from script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to convert a bash script to batch, but I am having a trouble for this one issue. The script runs a java server in the background, waits for 5 seconds, then exit with exitcode. But in batch, I am unable...

runserver.sh

```
java -jar java_server.jar &
pid=$!
sleep 5
kill -0 $pid
cmdStatus=$?
if [ $cmdStatus -ne 0 ]
then
exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

runserver.bat

```
@echo off
set EXITCODE=0 
start /b java -jar java_server.jar
timeout /t 5
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in ('jps -m ^| findstr java_server') do set PID=%%i
IF "%PID" == "" (
set EXITCODE=1
)
EXIT EXITCODE
```

but if I run the above batchscript, I am never able to disown the java process and it never exists

Comment: Remove the unneeded spaces between equal signs (`==`) in `if` in `runserver.bat`. Also, found a typo: `%PID%` instead of `%PID`. So, string `%PID` will **never** be equal to `""` (nothing), so your script will **always** exit with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake in batch file code is missing `%` in line `IF "%PID" == ""` to really compare the value of the environment variable `PID` enclosed in double quotes with the string `""`. So correct would be `IF "%PID%" == ""`. For more details on string comparisons see [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).

The second mistake is not using two times `%` on last command line `EXIT EXITCODE` around the environment variable `EXITCODE` to reference its value which would be correct written as `EXIT %EXITCODE%`.

But the batch file should be better written as follows:

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
start "" /B javaw.exe -jar "%~dp0java_server.jar"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NOBREAK >nul
jps -m 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L "java_server" >nul
```

The batch file first makes the directory of the batch file the current directory because of `java_server.jar` is most likely in directory of the batch file. `%~dp0` expands to drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file. The file path referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with a backslash which is the directory separator on Windows which should be taken into account on concatenating this string with a file or folder name. The command **CD** fails only if the batch file is stored on a network resource accessed with a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention) because of Windows prevents by default that a directory referenced with a UNC path instead of a drive letter becomes the current directory for downwards compatibility reasons because of many console applications work not correct with current directory not being on a drive with a drive letter.

The command **START** interprets first double quoted string as title for the console window opened on running a Windows console application in a separate command process. In this case no console window is opened because of using option `/B` although `java.exe` is a Windows console application. For that reason explicitly specifying an empty string with `""` as window title like on starting a Windows GUI application is advisable to avoid that any other double quoted argument string is interpreted as optional window title.

The option `/B` is interpreted as *background*. Most people think that the started application is detached from current command process. This is true for Windows GUI applications, but not for console applications like `java.exe`. The handle **STDIN** of current command process is bind with **STDIN** of started console application. Also the output to the handles **STDOUT** and **STDERR** of started application are redirected to console window of the running command process which nevertheless continues immediately with execution of batch script. The option `/B` means just running the console application parallel to current command process without opening a new console window, but not in running the application completely detached from running command process.

The solution is quite simple in this case because there is also `javaw.exe`, the Windows version of **Java** designed for running a Java application completely in background detached from the process starting it.

A batch file for general usage works best on specifying all files with full qualified file name which means with full path, file name and file extension. **Java** executable can be installed everywhere and so the folder path for this executable can't be specified in the batch file. Windows command processor has to find the executable `javaw` in current directory or in any folder in list of folders of **local** environment variable `PATH`. But it is at least possible to specify the executable `javaw` with its file extension `.exe` as this file extension is well known.

The JAR file `java_server.jar` is specified with full path on assuming that this file is stored in same directory as the batch file. The batch file directory should be already the current directory and so `%~dp0` would not be needed at all, but it does not matter to specify the file for safety with full path.

Next the standard Windows console application **TIMEOUT** is called with full qualified file name with options to wait 5 seconds unbreakable (requires Windows 7 or newer) and redirecting its output to device **NUL**.

I don't know anything about the file `jps` and have not even installed Java. For that reason I assume `jps` is an executable or script of which file extension listed in **local** environment variable `PATHEXT` and stored in directory of the batch file or any other directory of which path is listed in **local** environment variable `PATH`. It would be of course better to specify this file with file extension and if possible also with full path.

The standard output of `jps` is redirected to standard input of Windows standard console application **FINDSTR** and the error output to device **NUL** to suppress it.

**FINDSTR** runs a case-sensitive, literal string search for `java_server` on standard output of `jps`. The output of **FINDSTR** is of no interest and therefore redirected also to device **NUL** to suppress it.

**FINDSTR** exits with `0` on searched string really found and with `1` on nothing found. The batch file should exit with `1` on not successfully starting Java server and with `0` on Java server running. This matches exactly with exit code of **FINDSTR** and so nothing else must be done.

`cmd.exe` exits the execution of a batch file always with last exit code set by an application or command during batch file execution. This can be verified on commenting out second command line with `rem` and save it, running this batch file from within a command prompt window and running next in command prompt window `if errorlevel 1 echo Java server not running!` resulting in expected output `Java server not running!`. Then `rem` needs to be removed from second command line of batch file before saving the batch file which is run once again from within the command prompt window. After second batch file execution finished, running once again `if errorlevel 1 echo Java server not running!` results in no output while running `if errorlevel 0 echo Java server is running.` results in output `Java server is running.` as expected.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0`
- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `if /?`
- `start /?`

See also:

- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/which-cmd-exe-internal-commands-clear-the-errorlevel-to-0-upon-success)