# Best Practice - Testing Batch Commands for ErrorLevel

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My batch file runs several registry edit commands, and I want to implement a conditional if said registry edit commands return error levels. My question is: should I wrap these commands in a function, or create the error levels conditional after EVERY registry command? My concern regarding wrapping these commands into a function is that not every command will get checked. I want to ensure that each command gets checked, and returns an error level.

The code chunk for wrapping the commands in a function could be incorrect or missing pieces. Not sure if I need to include an EXIT at the conclusion of each function? This is apart of a multi-step batch script.

```
TITLE Disable UAC
ECHO STEP 1: Disable User Account Control
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO An error was found w/ error code of: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

or

```
:disable_uac
TITLE Disable UAC
ECHO STEP 1: Disable User Account Control
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

call :disable_uac
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO An error was found w/ error code of: %ERRORLEVEL$
```

Regarding the first code chunk, I assume that the ERRORLEVEL conditional is only going to return the error code of the LAST command rather than the both?

Updated Code:

```
@echo off
goto ErrorCheck

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ECHO STEP 1: Copy Folder
robocopy "C:\Users\!username!\Documents\WindowsSetup\Training_Videos" "C:\Users\!username!\Desktop\Training_Videos" /e /copyall
CMD /K

:ErrorCheck
title Disable UAC
for /F "useback skip=2 delims= eol=" %%I in ("%~f0") do (
    IF "%%~I" == ":ErrorCheck" exit /B
    ECHO %%I
    %%I >>"C:\errorlog.log"
    if errorlevel 1 exit /B & ECHO You have encountered an issue. Look at Error Log for more information
)
```

Comment: Yes, ERRORLEVEL refers only to the last command, it gets overwritten as soon as you execute another command.

Comment: So if I were to not wrap those 2 commands in a function, then I would need to call that ERRORLEVEL if statement twice if I want both of commands to be checked?

Comment: How often you _need_ to check for errors depends on what you're doing. In this case an error from the first reg command doesn't have to mean that the second reg command will also fail (because they write to different registry locations). But perhaps there's still no point in proceeding with the script, so you might still _want to_ check for errors after every command. (BTW why do you write "EVERY" in caps? Error handling is necessary -- don't think of it as a nuisance!)

Comment: I don't understand the second option you proposed. It looks like that script is just going to loop forever with no error checking...

Comment: Use a `for` loop or have the `%errorlevel%` after each command.

Comment: What about using conditional execution on fail by appending `|| (echo this command failed)` ?

Comment: I'm going to opt for the ````for```` loop as it's not ideal to have ````&errorlevel&```` after every command. I'm unsure how to implement it tho as not every registry command follows the same path as the ones noted in the OP. Some of my registry commands are located in different paths, but I would like to bundle them as they are apart of 1 step. Looking for guidance more so than asking someone to write the code. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how the `for` loop lets you avoid error checking after each command. Isn't the error checking going to happen inside the loop? But yeah, it will probably result in a shorter script with less duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution to run multiple commands written in a batch file with suppressing standard output written to handle **STDOUT** and error messages written to handle **STDERR** with exiting batch file execution on first command or executable exiting with an exit code **greater or equal** `1` is:

```
@echo off
goto MainCode

reg.exe add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg.exe add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

:MainCode
title Disable UAC
for /F "useback skip=2 delims= eol=" %%I in ("%~f0") do (
    if "%%~I" == ":MainCode" exit /B
    echo %%I
    %%I >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 exit /B
)
```

This batch file executes all non-empty lines defined in the batch file below second line because of `skip=2` on **FOR** loop command line and the label line `:MainCode`.

These command lines cannot contain environment variable references with the code as provided because of the environment variable references would not be expanded by Windows command processor before execution. It is of course possible to use command `call` to force an additional parsing of a command line during **FOR** loop execution to expanded environment variable references.

The command lines between `goto MainCode` and `:MainCode` also cannot contain redirection operators like `<`, `>`, `>>` and `|`. The redirections are done by `cmd.exe` executing the batch file. Windows command processor must recognize them already on parsing the command line before execution. So when `cmd.exe` parses the command line `%%I >nul 2>nul` before execution, it recognizes the redirections `>nul` and `2>nul` before execution of whatever is currently assigned to loop variable `I`, but `cmd.exe` will never recognize such redirections specified on command line assigned to loop variable `I`.

See also [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

The execution of this demonstration batch file is exited immediately on first command/executable exiting with a value **greater or equal** `1`. The commands **IF** and **EXIT** don't modify variable `errorlevel` and so the calling process gets the exit code of the failed command/executable.

See also:

- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)

The exit code of the batch file is `0` on no command exits with a value **greater or equal** `1`.

**FOR** opens here the batch file already executed by `cmd.exe` specified with `%~f0` which expands to drive + path + name + extension of the batch file itself because of option `/F` and processes it line by line.

The option `usebackq` is necessary to get the full batch file name enclosed in `"` interpreted as file name of which lines should be processed instead of interpreting the full qualified batch file name itself as string to process by **FOR**.

The option `skip=2` tells **FOR** to skip the first two lines of the opened file and start processing the lines with third line.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores always empty lines. Lines starting with a semicolon are ignored also by **FOR** on usage of option `/F` because of `eol=;` is the default end of line definition. For that reason `eol=` is used to define no end of line character resulting in not ignoring lines starting with a semicolon.

**FOR** splits up by default every non-empty line read from file into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign only first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here. The entire line as written in the batch file should be assigned to loop variable `I`. For that reason `delims=` is specified to define an empty list of string delimiting characters which disables line splitting behavior completely.

The main code of the batch file could be also written as follows:

```
title Disable UAC
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.log" 2>nul
for /F "useback skip=2 delims= eol=" %%I in ("%~f0") do (
    if "%%~I" == ":MainCode" goto Finished
    %%I >nul 2>>"%TEMP%\%~n0.log" || exit /B
)
:Finished
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.log" 2>nul
exit /B 0
```

This variant of the batch file runs the commands/executables silently with suppressing standard output and logging error output into a file in folder for temporary files with name of batch file with file extension `.log`.

The loop is exited if any command/executable exits with a value not equal 0 with the exit code of last executed command/executable or on reaching label line with deletion of the empty log file and exit code 0.

And even more enhanced version is:

```
@echo off
goto MainCode

e   TITLE Disable UAC
c   echo Errors are log into file: "%TEMP%\%~n0.log"
p   STEP 1: Disable User Account Control
r   reg.exe add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
r   reg.exe add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

:MainCode
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.log" 2>nul
for /F "useback skip=2 tokens=1* eol=" %%I in ("%~f0") do (
    if %%I == :MainCode del "%TEMP%\%~n0.log" 2>nul & exit /B 0
    if %%I == c (
        call %%J
    ) else if %%I == e (
        %%J
    ) else if %%I == p (
        echo(%%J
    ) else (
        %%J >nul 2>>"%TEMP%\%~n0.log" || exit /B
    )
)
```

There is a single character at beginning of each command line to execute in **FOR** loop controlling how to execute this line. The character is separated from the command line with one or more spaces or a horizontal tab character. The meaning of the execution control characters is as follows:

- **c** ... call this command line with command **CALL** to expand environment variable references before execution and do not suppress any output and do not evaluate exit code.
- **e** ... execute this command line without suppressing any output with no evaluation of exit code.
- **p** ... this line contains just text to print (into console window) with command **ECHO**.
- **r** ... run this command line with suppressing standard output and with logging error output to log file and with exiting batch file execution on exit code of command/executable is not `0` indicating a not successful execution.

The `(` between `echo` and `%%J` makes it possible to print also a blank line by inserting in command block a line with just `p`.

The **FOR** option `delims=` is replaced by `tokens=1*`. The line splitting behavior of **FOR** with the default delimiters space and tab is wanted here. The first space/tab delimited string should be assigned to loop variable `I` which is here the command execution controlling character at beginning of each line to execute or output respectively the label `:MainCode`. Everything after spaces/tabs after first string assigned to loop variable `I` should be not split up further on spaces/tabs. For that reason `*` is appended to `tokens=1` which tells **FOR** to assign the rest of the line after the spaces/tabs after `c`, `e`, `p` or `r` to next loop variable according to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is the character `J`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~f0` ... full file name of argument 0, i.e. batch file name with file extension and with full path as well as `%~n0` which expands to just file name of batch file without file extension and path.
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?` ... explains that `if ERRORLEVEL number` means if `ERRORLEVEL` is **greater or equal** `number` and *not equal* `number` as many people not reading help/documentation think.
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the operators `&` and `||`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using conditional execution, e.g.:

```
@echo off
CALL :DISABLEUAC || GOTO :ERRHANDLER
GOTO :EOF

:DISABLEUAC
ECHO STEP 1: Disable User Account Control
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\... /f || GOTO :EOF
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\... /f || GOTO :EOF
GOTO :EOF

:ERRHANDLER
ECHO An error was found w/ error code of: %ERRORLEVEL%
GOTO :EOF
```

- Within the DISABLEUAC subroutine, use conditional execution to exit the subroutine if a command fails
- In the main module, call the subroutine and use conditional execution to jump to an error handler if the subroutine fails.