# How to branch after %ERRORLEVEL% check to IF-ELSE branch in a batch file by checking two separate strings?

Tags: batch-file

The batch file with the following code branches depending on `%ERRORLEVEL%` condition. `set result=PASSED` is executed if string `OK` is found in output. The batch file should also search for string `ERROR` in addition to `OK` string in output and should execute `set result=FAILED` if `ERROR` is found in output.

How can I do this?

```
rem ...
rem ...
call myCommand.cmd | FIND "OK" > NUL

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    set result=PASSED
    set /A passedCounter=passedCounter+1
) else (
    set result=FAILED
    set /A failedCounter=failedCounter+1
)
rem ...
rem ...
```

Comment: Is it feasible to run the first line again but search for ERROR this time? Otherwise, you'll have to redirect the output of `call mycommand.cmd` to a file and do searches on that. Either way, you need a separate ` find` command.

Comment: It will repeat the same command (myCommand.cmd) consecutively, which is not desirable.

Comment: Something doesn't look right with your question. If you really need to check for both OK and ERROR, then you need to consider if both are found, or if neither is found. If it is always exactly one or the other, but never both, then your existing logic is likely good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file code could be used for this task.

```
@echo off
call myCommand.cmd | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L "OK ERROR" >"%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" || goto Failed
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L "ERROR" "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" >nul && goto Failed

set "result=PASSED"
set /A passedCounter+=1
goto Done

:Failed
set "result=FAILED"
set /A failedCounter+=1

:Done
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" 2>nul
echo Result is: %result%
```

**FINDSTR** searches in standard output of batch file `myCommand.cmd`

- case-insensitive because of option `I`
- and literally because of option `/L`
- for string `OK` **OR** string `ERROR`.

The space character inside double quoted search string is interpreted in this case by **FINDSTR** as **OR** expression.

The exit code of **FINDSTR** is `1` if neither `OK` nor `ERROR` could be found which should be interpreted as failed operation and so processing of batch file is continued on command line below the line with label `Failed`.

Otherwise the one or more lines containing `OR` **OR** `ERROR` output by **FINDSTR** are written into a temporary file in directory for temporary files with name of batch file as file name and file extension `.tmp`.

This temporary file with output of first executed **FINDSTR** is searched once again with **FINDSTR** this time searching case-insensitive and literally only for the string `ERROR` and suppressing the output by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

**FINDSTR** exits with `0` if there is a line with `ERROR` resulting in processing of batch file is continued on command line below the line with label `Failed`.

Otherwise the output of batch file `myCommand.cmd` contains `OK`, but not `ERROR` and so the task was accomplished successfully.

Finally the temporary file is deleted on existing at all with suppressing the error message on not existing by redirecting the error message to device **NUL** and the result is printed into console window.

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))

Another solution not using a temporary file:

```
@echo off
set "result="
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('myCommand.cmd ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L "OK ERROR"') do (
    echo %%I | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L "ERROR" >nul && goto Failed
    set "result=PASSED"
)
if defined result set /A "passedCounter+=1" & goto Done

:Failed
set "result=FAILED"
set /A failedCounter+=1

:Done
echo Result is: %result%
```

**FOR** with option `/F` starts a new command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line as specified in the round brackets between the two `'` which means with Windows directory on drive C: the execution of the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c myCommand.cmd | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L "OK ERROR"
```

The redirection operator `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDOUT** of background command process and processes the captured text line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** would split up each non-empty line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab separated substring to specified loop variable `I` if not starting with default end of line character `;`. This line splitting behavior with ignoring entire line on starting with a semicolon without or with leading spaces/tabs is not wanted here. For that reason `delims= eol=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters to disable line splitting behavior and define no end of line character. It is necessary to specify these two options without using double quotes which means the equal signs and the space character must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal characters and not as argument separators.

Each line output by **FINDSTR** in separate command process is searched for string `ERROR` and if indeed found the loop execution is exited with a jump to command line below line with label `Failed`. Otherwise this line must contain `OK` and so the environment variable `result` is defined now with value `PASSED`. But there could be one more line with `ERROR` and so the loop is not exited in this case.

If the environment variable `result` is defined after execution of **FOR** there was a line output by batch file `myCommand.cmd` with `OK` and none with `ERROR` which means the task was accomplished successfully.

BTW: It would be much easier if the batch file `myCommand.cmd` would exit with `0` on success and a value greater `0` on any error. This could be very easily evaluated by the calling batch file.

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`