# How can I fix spaces in the Sublime Text Build-System python path?

Tags: python, cmd, sublimetext, sublime-build

I am using Sublime Text 4 and I have a problem trying to set up a Build-System for running Python programs on the cmd console. I think it is caused by an space in  the name of one of the directories in my path, I have spent hours looking for solutions on many different sites (I know very little about how the Build-System logic works in general), and I am not able to fix it. I've tried using the (^), (*), and (') symbols to indicate the space character, and also to quote the hole path (which worked pasting it on de console, but not specifiying it from the Build-System), but none of them has worked for me.

The code is the following (I copied it from a youtube tutorial, and it worked fine without spaces in the python path):

```
{
"shell_cmd": "start cmd /C \"(C:/Program Files/Python/python.exe \"$file\" || set /p = Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...) && set /p = Successful execution. Press Enter to exit...\"",
"selector": "source.python",
"working_dir": "$file_dir"}
```

And the cmd console returned this (translated from Spanish):

```
"C:/Program" it is not recognized as an internal or external command executable program or batch file. Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...
```

Any idea if there is anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is using the string:

```
"start %ComSpec% /D /S /C \"(\"C:\\Program Files\\Python\\python.exe\" \"$file\" || set /p =Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...) && set /p =Successful execution. Press Enter to exit...\""
```

The usage of `shell_cmd` results in starting in background without a visible console window `cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the command line specified in next string using the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with an appropriate filled [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure.

How the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` interprets the argument string(s) after the option `/c` is explained by the help output on running `cmd /?` in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window. There are five conditions which define the general behavior on interpreting the argument string(s) after option `/c` (or option `/k`) and the first one is the usage of option `/S` left to option `/C` or `/K`.

How the Windows command processor instance is started by *Sublime Text 4* on using `shell_cmd` cannot be controlled by the user. In this case is executed in the background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start %ComSpec% /D /S /C "("C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" "$file" || set /p =Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...) && set /p =Successful execution. Press Enter to exit..."
```

`$file` is replaced by the file name string by *Sublime Text 4* before starting the Windows command processor.

For that reason the command line is coded in a manner to work with `cmd.exe /c` as used by *Sublime Text 4*. The free Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can be used to see what happens in background when an executable starts another executable. After double clicking on a process in log of Process Monitor and selecting tab **Process** the *Command Line* can be seen used to start the process.

A visible console window is wanted in this case which is the reason why the internal command `start` is used to start one more instance of `cmd.exe`. The usage of `start` results in using again the function `CreateProcess`, but this time by the `cmd` instance started by *Sublime Text 4*, with using a `STARTUPINFO` filled to open a new console window by `CreateProcess` on starting the executable.

The executable to start is `cmd.exe` specified with its full qualified file name by referencing the value of the predefined Windows environment variable `ComSpec` with `%ComSpec%` which is expanded by first started `cmd.exe` instance already to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` on Windows being installed in `C:\Windows` before executing command `start`. `ComSpec` is a system environment variable defined by default with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`. So it would be also possible to replace `%ComSpec%` by `%SystemRoot%\\System32\\cmd.exe` in the command line string.

The second instance of `cmd` should be started with ignoring the `AutoRun` registry string value which does not exist by default in Windows registry. That is for security and makes the starting process of second `cmd` instance a little bit faster. More information about option `/D` and the `AutoRun` registry string value can be read in help of Windows command processor output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window.

The option `/S` is used to explicitly define how the second `cmd` instance should interpret the argument strings after the next option `/C` which is for executing a command line and closing `cmd` after finishing the command line execution.

The command line to execute contains the conditional operators `&&` and `||` as explained in detail by [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) and twice an equal sign. For that reason it is highly recommended to enclose the entire command line string in `"` to get these operators and the equal signs interpreted as literal characters by first `cmd` instance started by *Sublime Text 4* when it parses the argument strings after option `/c`, i.e. the entire coded command line string.

The second `cmd` instance removes the first and the last `"` from the argument string after option `/C` because of option `/S` and interprets the remaining command line for execution.

In can be read in help of `cmd` that a file name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` (and also `<>|` not possible in a file name) must be enclosed in `"` to be interpreted as literal character. `C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe` contains a space character which is interpreted as argument string separator on not being inside a double quoted argument string. Therefore the full qualified file name of Python executable must be enclosed in `"` to be interpreted as one argument string and not as the two argument strings `C:\Program` and `Files\Python\python.exe`.

The usage of `||` **and** `&&` makes it additionally necessary that the execution of Python with the command `set` executed on `python.exe` terminating itself with an exit value not equal 0 are combined in a command block by using a pair of `(` and `)` to get the `set` command after `&&` executed only if `python.exe` exited with value 0 for successful execution of the Python script.

For the special requirements caused by using `||` and `&&` see:

- [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)

So the second started `cmd` instance with a visible console window runs the command line:

```
("C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" "$file" || set /p =Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...) && set /p =Successful execution. Press Enter to exit...
```

The `cmd` instance started first by *Sublime Text 4* closes itself already after successful start of second `cmd` instance by internal command `start`. In other words the second `cmd` executes `python.exe` with `CreateProcess` with a `STARTUPINFO` to use the console window and the input, output and error streams of second `cmd` while first `cmd` exited itself already which means for *Sublime Text 4* that the execution of the tool finished already although in real second `cmd.exe` and `python.exe` are still running.