# Copy a specific image among several images contained in different subfolders, in a specific folder (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, copy, subdirectory

How can I copy a particular image to a default position? The image, in question, is located in the folder at the deepest level. The folder in question is contained in other nested subfolders (e.g. packages, themes, variants, etc...), in a tree structure. This little program should ask which directory it should go to and continue until it gets to that directory that actually contains the image needed and then copy it.

Here is the directory structure:

```
MainFolder
 ┗ PluginFolder
   ┗ LauncherFolder
     ┣ Cosmetics
     ┃ ┣ Default Pack
     ┃ ┃ ┗ Default Theme
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Character
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Chara.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Launcher
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┗ Launcher.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃
     ┃ ┗ Pack 1
     ┃ ┃ ┣ Default Theme
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Character
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Chara_A.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Chara_A1.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Launcher
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┗ Launcher_1.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃
     ┃ ┃ ┣ NW Theme
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Default
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Character
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Chara_B.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Launcher
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃   ┣ Launcher_2.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃   ┗ Launcher_2b.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃  
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Alternative 1
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┣ Character
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┃ ┣ Chara_C.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┃ ┗ Chara_C3.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┗ Launcher
     ┃ ┃ ┃     ┣ Launcher_3.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃     ┗ Launcher_3c.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃     
     ┃ ┃ ┗ SW Theme
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Character
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Chara_E.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Chara_F.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Launcher
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┣ Launcher_4.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃   ┗ Launcher_5.png
     ┃ ┃ ┃   
     ┣ Chara.png
     ┗ Launcher.png
```

This script is located in the `MainFolder`. The `Cosmetics` folder contains the Packs (for this example I put 2 but they can increase). The "png-searching" should start from here. Inside each `Pack` folder are `Themes`, and inside each one can be an `Alternative` Version. And finally we have the `Character` folder and the `Launcher` folder. The objective, as I said before, is to choose an image from those available in the `Cosmetics` directory and override the image (either Chara or Launcher) in the `LauncherFolder` with that. But to do that I have to direct the script to that specific png first. Then, after copying it, delete the old one and rename the new one.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be created first the folders and files for developing and testing the batch file for this menu driven file copying task according to the user´s decisions. The following batch file creates the directory structure and the PNG files which of course are not really portable network graphic image files, but text files with file extension `.png`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseFolder=C:\Temp"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Default Pack\Default Theme\Character"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Default Pack\Default Theme\Launcher"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Character"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Launcher"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Character"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Launcher"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Character"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Launcher"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Character"
md "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Launcher"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Default Pack\Default Theme\Character\Chara.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Default Pack\Default Theme\Character\Chara.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Default Pack\Default Theme\Launcher\Launcher.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Default Pack\Default Theme\Launcher\Launcher.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Character\Chara_A.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Character\Chara_A.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Character\Chara_A1.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Character\Chara_A1.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Launcher\Launcher_1.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\Default Theme\Launcher\Launcher_1.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Character\Chara_B.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Character\Chara_B.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Launcher\Launcher_2.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Launcher\Launcher_2.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Launcher\Launcher_2b.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Default\Launcher\Launcher_2b.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Character\Chara_C.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Character\Chara_C.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Character\Chara_C3.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Character\Chara_C3.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Launcher\Launcher_3.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Launcher\Launcher_3.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Launcher\Launcher_3c.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\NW Theme\Alternative 1\Launcher\Launcher_3c.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Character\Chara_E.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Character\Chara_E.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Character\Chara_F.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Character\Chara_F.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Launcher\Launcher_4.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Launcher\Launcher_4.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Launcher\Launcher_5.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics\Pack 1\SW Theme\Launcher\Launcher_5.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Chara.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Chara.png"
echo "%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Launcher.png">"%BaseFolder%\MainFolder\PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Launcher.png"
endlocal
```

The batch file for copying the PNG files is much more complex, especially when it should work with really all possible file and folder names with a space or one of these characters `` %&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "TargetFolder=%~dp0PluginFolder\LauncherFolder"
set "Workingfolder=%~dp0PluginFolder\LauncherFolder\Cosmetics"

if exist "%WorkingFolder%\" goto CheckChoice
echo(
echo ERROR: Folder "%WorkingFolder%" does not exist!
echo(
pause
exit /B 2

:CheckChoice
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe goto InitEnvironment
echo(
echo ERROR: The file "%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe" does not exist!
echo        This batch script cannot be used without executable choice.
echo(
pause
exit /B 3

:InitEnvironment
rem Delete all environment variables of which name starts with character #.
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%=I"
rem Initial number of PNG files in the Character or Launcher folder.
set "FileCount=0"
rem Initial number of subfolders in a pack or themes folder.
set "FolderCount=0"
rem A list of keys assigned to the files/folders whereby the first character
rem is just a dummy to have first choice key character at character index 1.
set "KeysList=#1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
rem The value below must be the number of keys listed above minus one.
rem This value determines also the maximum number of files/folders
rem from which the user can choose a file/folder.
set "MaxKeys=36"

rem Let the user choose a pack and next a theme folder.
call :GetFolder pack || exit /B
call :GetFolder theme || exit /B
rem Let the user choose between default or an alternative if the
rem theme folder does not contain already the "Character" folder.
if not exist "%WorkingFolder%\Character\" call :GetFolder alternative || exit B

if exist "%WorkingFolder%\Character\" goto CharacterFiles
echo(
echo ERROR: There is no folder "Character" in the folder:
echo        "%WorkingFolder%"
echo(
pause
exit /B 2

:CharacterFiles
if exist "%WorkingFolder%\Character\*.png" goto LauncherFolder
echo(
echo ERROR: There is no PNG file in the character folder:
echo        "%WorkingFolder%\Character"
echo(
pause
exit /B 1

:LauncherFolder
if exist "%WorkingFolder%\Launcher\" goto LauncherFiles
echo(
echo ERROR: There is no folder "Launcher" in the folder:
echo        "%WorkingFolder%"
echo(
pause
exit /B 2

:LauncherFiles
if exist "%WorkingFolder%\Launcher\*.png" goto CopyFiles
echo(
echo ERROR: There is no PNG file in the launcher folder:
echo        "%WorkingFolder%\Launcher"
echo(
pause
exit /B 1

:CopyFiles
call :CopyFile character Chara
call :CopyFile launcher Launcher
rem Exit the batch file after copying the two PNG files.
exit /B 0


:GetFolder
rem Set up a new local environment for the subroutine GetFolder.
setlocal
rem Change the current working directory to the working folder.
pushd "%WorkingFolder%"
rem Search for non-hidden folders in the current working directory
rem and create a list of folder names with counting the folders.
rem Folders with an exclamation mark in name are supported too.
for /D %%I in (*) do (
    set /A FolderCount+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%J in (!FolderCount!) do (
        endlocal
        set "#Folder%%J=%%I"
        if %%J == %MaxKeys% popd & goto FolderMenu
    )
)
popd
rem Is there only one folder in the current working folder?
if %FolderCount% == 1 goto SelectFolder
if %FolderCount% == 0 goto NoFolder

:FolderMenu
echo(
echo Available %1 folders:
echo(
rem Set up an environment with enabled delayed variable expansion for the menu.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,%FolderCount%) do echo   !KeysList:~%%I,1! ... !#Folder%%I!
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C !KeysList:~1,%FolderCount%! /N /M "Your choice:"
if not errorlevel 1 goto FolderMenu
set "WorkingFolder=!WorkingFolder!\!#Folder%ERRORLEVEL%!"
rem End the environment with enabled delayed variable expansion for the
rem menu and next the local environment of the subroutine with passing
rem twice the extended working folder path to the previous environment.
endlocal & set "WorkingFolder=%WorkingFolder%"
endlocal & set "WorkingFolder=%WorkingFolder%"
exit /B 0

:SelectFolder
rem Select the single available folder automatically without user prompt.
endlocal & set "WorkingFolder=%WorkingFolder%\%#Folder1%"
exit /B 0

:NoFolder
endlocal
echo(
echo ERROR: There is no %1 folder in the folder:
echo        "%WorkingFolder%"
echo(
pause
exit /B 2


:CopyFile
rem Set up a new local environment for the subroutine CopyFile.
setlocal
rem Change the current working directory to the working folder as defined
rem by the environment variable WorkingFolder and the folder name passed
rem as first argument to the subroutine CopyFile.
pushd "%WorkingFolder%\%1"
rem Search for non-hidden PNG files in the current working directory
rem and create a list of file names with counting the files.
rem Files with an exclamation mark in name are supported too.
for %%I in (*.png) do (
    set /A FileCount+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%J in (!FileCount!) do (
        endlocal
        set "#File%%J=%%I"
        if %%J == %MaxKeys% goto FileMenu
    )
)
rem Is there more than one file in the current working folder?
if not %FileCount% == 1 goto FileMenu

rem Copy the single available PNG file to the target directory with file name
rem as defined by the second argument string passed the subroutine GetFile.
copy /B /Y "%#File1%" "%TargetFolder%\%2.png" >nul
rem Restore the initial environment as on call of this subroutine.
popd
endlocal
goto :EOF

:FileMenu
echo(
echo Available %1 files:
echo(
rem Set up an environment with enabled delayed variable expansion for the menu.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,%FileCount%) do echo   !KeysList:~%%I,1! ... !#File%%I!
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C !KeysList:~1,%FileCount%! /N /M "Your choice:"
if not errorlevel 1 goto FileMenu
copy /B /Y "!#File%ERRORLEVEL%!" "!TargetFolder!\%2.png" >nul
rem Restore the initial environment as on call of this subroutine.
endlocal
popd
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

Please read the comment lines beginning with command `rem` to get a brief description on how this batch file works.

The batch file processing can be exited with four different exit codes:

- `0` ... no error.
- `1` ... no PNG file in user selected `Character` or `Launcher` folder.
- `2` ... a folder is missing in the directory structure selected by the user.
- `3` ... the [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) **CHOICE** is not available as it is the case by default on Windows XP.

The batch file processing is always paused on an error before exiting because of the batch file is mainly used by a user with double clicking on the batch file and not called by another batch file or run from within an already opened command prompt window.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `set /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `exit /?`
- `call /?`
- `rem /?`
- `copy /?`
- `choice /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `popd /?`

There should be read additionally the following pages for a full understanding of the command lines in the batch file.

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
  It explains the processing of a batch file with one or more subroutines with `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` used to either exit a subroutine or exit the processing of the batch file without or with an explicit specified exit code value for the calling function or process.
- [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/)
  It explains when and how [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is required like the usage help output on executing `set /?` in a command prompt window. The batch file could be less complex on enabling delayed variable expansion only once at top of the batch file, but then it would not work correct if any folder or file name contains one or more exclamation marks.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/which-cmd-exe-internal-commands-clear-the-errorlevel-to-0-upon-success)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
  The reason for using `echo(` to output an empty line can be read there.
- [How to pass environment variables as parameters by reference to another batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564)
  This answer describes in full details what happens on each execution of **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** and how to pass one or more environment variables from the current environment to the previous environment.
- [Syntax error in one of two almost-identical batch scripts: ")" cannot be processed syntactically here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564)
  This answer describes several common issues in batch file coding and how to prevent a not working batch file by following some simple rules on coding the batch file.
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
  Why the command **CHOICE** is used instead of prompting the user with `set /P` is explained in full details by the answer on this question.